# Article when there is an adjective before a noun

Tags: grammar, adjectives, articles

**When to use *a* or *an* before a noun** when there are adjectives before that noun?

like the following example:

> An operator pressed the button.

should that make:

> **A** professional **operator** pressed the button.
>
> **An** professional **operator** pressed the button.

same for:

> **A** Hypertext markup language.
>
> **An** Hypertext markup language.

Sometimes it seems a bit confusing, especially when there are more adjectives like:

> **An omen** was revealed to the priest.
>
> **A** terrible **omen** was revealed to the priest.
>
> **An** overwhelming terrible **omen** was revealed to the priest.

What is the rule?

Comment: The rule is exactly the same, regardless of adjectives/adverbs/anything being before the noun: **There's a consonant sound?** Use _a_. **There's a vowel sound?** Usa _an_. There are many questions about the articles a/an, like [A historic or An historic](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/629/a-historic-or-an-historic), for example, or ["Use of A versus An"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/use-of-a-versus-an)...

Comment: @Alenanno thank you for your response. I did looked up similar questions, however, the queries I entered yielded no results. I can close this question since it is a duplicate ? ;)

Comment: @Caspar: I'm not sure you can close it by yourself... I voted to close it, eheh, we must wait for others to close it. I understand you didn't find them, anyway, I was having a hard time as well! lol :D

Comment: A/An refers to the exact noun after them.

Comment: @Caspar: thanks for flagging this yourself, this is really appreciated. The site search doesn't work for a whole number of short and common words such as *a* or *an*, so no one will say that this was a failure on your part. What I can recommend instead is having a look at the ["faq" tab under "Questions"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=faq), or [googling using the "site:" operator](http://www.google.com/search?q=a+an+site%3Aenglish.stackexchange.com). Cheers.

Comment: @RegDwightthanks for the tips, I'll keep them in mind ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The article changes based on the word immediately following, not necessarily on the noun.  There is no difference in meaning between "a" and "an" - the distinction is used to preserve an alternation between vowels and consonants when the sentence is spoken aloud.

Be aware that speakers of American and British English observe different rules (mainly because we can't agree on whether to pronounce the letter H or not!)

In your example:

```
A Hypertext Markup language. An Hypertext markup language.
```

an American speaker (and, to be honest, most British speakers) would find the first one correct, while an exaggerated aitch-dropper would use the second.

In these examples:

```
An omen was revealed to the priest.
A terrible omen was revealed to the priest.
An overwhelming terrible omen was revealed to the priest.
```

all three are correct as written, whether the speaker is American or British.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_(grammar)#Indefinite_article