# Why don't we use the indefinite article in "what hassle"?

Tags: grammaticality, indefinite-articles

Why don't we use the indefinite article in "what hassle"?

I think *hassle* is used as noun here which means "Irritating or inconvenience". What exactly is the problem with "what a hassle" (as hassle is third-person singular)?

Comment: Where did you see "what hassle"? In fact, the normal expression of exasperation at a bothersome task is "what a hassle" ...

Comment: I noticed in a magazine,I am also keen to know why do we use 'a' here while we use 'an' for historian?

Comment: [This](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=a+hassle%2Can+hassle&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=50) is interesting,[however](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=what+a+hassle%2Cwhat+an+hassle&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) :/

Comment: And for historian,I am a bit of [confused](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=what+a+historian%2Cwhat+an+historian&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) too.

Comment: Whatever magazine you read it in, "what hassle" is definitely not standard usage. On your *historian* search, try removing the "what" portion for improved clarity -- http://j.mp/ngram-a-historian-an-historian -- and then try the same with *history*: http://j.mp/ngram-a-history-an-history

Comment: Philando Gullible: See **nohat**'s excellent answer re *historian*. The issue doesn't arise with *hassle*... http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/629/a-historic-or-an-historic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the common phrase to express annoyance is "what **a** hassle", similar to "what a nuisance", "what a pain", and so on.

But saying "What hassle" is not entirely ungrammatical, because *hassle* can be used as an uncountable noun (to mean "hassle as a general concept", rather than a specific instance of it happening) which then cannot take *a/an*. This would be parallel to such expressions as "What fun!", "What larks" and so on - but as the latter example illustrates, this comes across somewhat stilted and literary.

(As for *a* versus *an*, that is well covered [elsewhere on this site](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/629/a-historic-or-an-historic).)

Comment: Effectively, OP's question as asked is a bit meaningless. If he'd asked "Why *do* we use..." it would have made more sense. Whatever - you've covered the whole issue perfectly well, I think.