# Why we say "an historical" but "a history"

Tags: pronunciation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I use “a” versus “an” in front of a word beginning with the letter h?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/629/when-should-i-use-a-versus-an-in-front-of-a-word-beginning-with-the-letter-h)

Why do we say *an historical* but *a history*? This question was originally posed by @shanselman [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/#!/shanselman/status/131840891676672001).

Comment: came here to ask this on his behalf ;-)

Comment: Some of us don't :-) I always pronounce the "h" in "historical", and I would say "a historical"

Comment: You say "we" as if it applies to most people. IMHO, it doesn't.

Comment: Not really @jcolebrand I just wanted to give credit where credit is due.

Comment: @Josh and Mahnax I think there's a disagreement about how it should be pronounced. I wanted to know which is correct and why.

Comment: @Amr: currently everybody agrees that "a historical", with the "h" pronounced, is correct. There is disagreement on whether "an historical", with the "h" not (or barely) pronounced, is also correct. This second pronunciation used to be much more common than it is now.

Comment: @Peter I don't agree :)

Comment: This question is not a duplicate and should not have been closed, I'm very grateful it was asked, thanks!

Comment: In "history", the first syllable is stressed, in "historical", the second syllable is stressed, which means the starting "h" is less harsh.

Comment: @z7sg Ѫ You're supposed to say why. A smiley face looks especially idiotic when you don't do so.

Answer (score 14):

I have a theory about this. In my speech, and I believe that of many other Americans, an "h" in an unstressed syllable is either not pronounced or barely pronounced, except when it follows a vowel sound or a pause. This is an adjustment that is made unconsciously; people often don't notice that they're not pronouncing the "h". I say "a historical", but "some istorical".

The rule for a/an is that you use "an" before words which start with a vowel sound, and "a" before words that start with a consonant sound.

Both "a historical" and "an (h)istorical" are consistent with these rules; here by (h), I mean the "h" is pronounced very lightly, if at all. Most people use the first, but some people use the second. I think nearly all Americans pronounce the "h" in "historical" when the word stands alone, but after an indefinite article, some drop the "h" and use "an".

In the word "history", the first syllable is stressed, so the "h" is always pronounced. So "an history" isn't allowed by these rules.

Comment: I disagree that *a historical* and *an historical* are "equally valid", but I think your answer best addresses why *an historical* is fairly common, while *an history* is universally regarded as an error.  For a more fleshed-out discussion, see [this](http://www.alphadictionary.com/articles/drgw007.html).

Comment: -1 The a/an rule doesn't depend on a following consonant/vowel *letter*, but a consonant/vowel *sound*: an hour and a half.

Comment: Hugo's comment is quite correct! "A" and "an" function as the indefinite forms of the grammatical article in the English language and can also represent the number one. *An* is the older form (related to one, cognate to German ein; etc.), now used before words starting with a vowel sound, regardless of whether the word begins with a vowel letter. Says [wikipedia] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_articles)  and my grammar books as well.

Comment: *Vehicle* versus *vehicular* is a common illustration of how the *h* which disappears from the start of unstressed syllables reappears when stressed.

Comment: @Hugo That's literally what the answer says. It was edited to say so explicitly even before you commented, but the basis of the entire answer is a discussion of its pronunciation. I'm confused.

Comment: @user84614 Internet archaeology time! My comment was in reply to something in [version 2 of the answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/47092/revisions), which Peter [acknowledged in a since deleted comment](https://web.archive.org/web/20130317054710/https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47090/why-we-say-an-historical-but-a-history) and corrected the answer, and I removed my down vote.

Comment: With much respect to Peter Shor, I'm skeptical about this process being the effective reason for use of *an historical* in modern American English. For example, I've never encountered *an heroic* in modern use, even though *heroic* starts with an unstressed syllable just as *historical* does. This leads me to suspect that *an historical* is a vestige of a time when *historical* was pronounced with a totally silent *h*. But I have to admit that pronouncing the *the* in *the historical* as if it preceded a vowel sound seems pretty "natural." So maybe there is something to this theory...

Answer (score 6):

Here are the final words of the relevant article in ‘The Cambridge Guide to English Usage’:

> Nowadays the silent *h* persists only in a handful of French loanwords
>   (*heir, honest, honour, hour* and their derivatives), and these need to
>   be preceded by *an*. The *h* of other loanwords like *heroic, hysterical*
>   and *hypothesis* may have been silent or varied in earlier times,
>   leaving uncertainty as to whether *an* was required or not. But their
>   pronunciation is no longer variable and provides no phonetic
>   justification for *an*. Its use with them is a stylistic nicety, lending
>   historical nuances to discourse in which tradition dies hard.

I broadly go along with that, noting at the same time that *h*-dropping more widely is a feature of some regional and social accents, and that in such cases the indefinite pronoun may indeed be realised as /an/.

Comment: Yes, but people used to say ["an hereafter"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+hereafter%2Can+hereafter&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) as well. That comes from Old English.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the main reason so many people say *an historical* is simply that they were taught that way.  It's a special exception to the "use 'a' before a consonant sound" rule, and it seems older generations of English speakers were often specifically taught this special case.

The fact is that *a historical* is perfectly correct, more logical, and preferred by a large number of English experts.  And it is overwhelmingly overtaking *an historical* in modern usage (see [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+historical%2C+an+historical&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)).

While I agree that the practice most likely originated as Peter Shor describes; namely, that many speakers do not (or only barely) pronounce the 'h' in *historical*, due to it being unstressed; I believe this phenomenon is not particularly strong in American English.  I would guess it began in Britain (and probably continues more strongly there), with its [h-dropping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_dropping) dialects.

Comment: I would disagree, in that I don't think most of the speakers who do this are choosing to do it deliberately; it's naturally part of their dialect. I believe that these same speakers would naturally say /ði/ (h)istorical rather than /ðə/ historical. However, you are right in that this practice does seem to be slowly dying out.

Comment: As an American English speaker, my experience is like that of John Y, that use of *an historical* is mostly taught, not "natural." For example, I've almost never encountered *an heroic*, even though *heroic* starts with an unstressed syllable just like *historical*.

Answer (score 3):

Some speakers drop the "h" sound in the word "historical", which means that the consonant "n" needs to be added to the article "a". However, it's been quite a while since I last heard this, everyone I know says "historic" with the sound "h" pronounced.

Background information: this word has been taken from Greek, but apparently it entered the English language via French. In French the letter "h" isn't pronounced, hence the English imitation which has now become outdated

Comment: But people but put "an" before words that start with an "h" in an unaccented syllable, whether or not they are derived from French. Consider the word "hysterical". It comes from [Latin](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hysterical), and it is preceded by "an" quite often, according to [Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+hysterical%2C+a+hysterical&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Comment: Similarly, In words starting "hu", where the pronunciation is /hj/, a decline in use of "an" occured circa 1800 rather than in the middle of the 20th century (see ["humanity"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+humanity%2C+an+humanity&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) or "heuristic"). It's a purely phonetic phenomenon, and has nothing to do with word origin.

Comment: All the words that you mention are of foreign origin. "hysterical" is a Greek word, still used today. "humanity" and "heuristic" are indeed of latin origin. The reason I think these words  passed to the English language from French is very simple: the French language is older than English. It is a rule in French never to pronounce the "h" sound, something which happens only on occasion in English, so I guess it was an imitation of the French accent. I believe it has indeed a lot to do with word origin.

Comment: Correction: "heuristic" is a Greek word, not Latin.

Comment: "an" used to go with ["hereafter"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+hereafter%2Can+hereafter&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) as well, which is definitely of Anglo-Saxon origin. I still claim it's a phonetic phenomenon.