# A/an hypothesis?

Tags: american-english, british-english

Is it `a` or `an` hypothesis? I am not a native speaker (and not very language talented) so I would appreciate any explanation/rules.

Comment: Use "a." As a rule, whenever the "h" is pronounced out loud, we use "a." Unfortunately, you have to consult a dictionary for each individual word to see whether the "h" is silent or pronounced, but it's usually pronounced.

Comment: You should use *a hypothesis*; although a minority of native speakers say *an hypothesis*, that's a more complicated rule to learn, and if you use it you risk sounding like a pretentious British snob. See [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47090/why-we-say-an-historical-but-a-history).

Comment: This question has been asked [many times](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/629/when-should-i-use-a-versus-an-in-front-of-a-word-beginning-with-the-letter-h) before. Please search the site before asking. The ["Frequent" tab under "Questions"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent) is a good place to start. Thank you.

Comment: British newsreaders (and I) say _an historic_.

Comment: @RegDwigнt The 'Frequent tab under Questions' didn't show me anything at all...

Answer (score 7):

In US usage, words beginning with a silent *h* take *an* as if they began with a vowel

> *an honor*

Words that begin with *h* in an accented or stressed syllable take *a*

> *a haircut*

Words that begin with *h* in an unaccented (unstressed) syllable can take either

> *an historic occasion*
>
> *a historic occasion*

In the first version, following *an*, the *h* is often effectively silent, but both pronunciations are heard.

The use of *a* in this last case is much more common, and the use of *an* may be viewed by some as a bit pompous, but surely correct.

Comment: So which one is it for hypothesis??

Comment: @emcor Either could be used, but in the US, *a* is more common.

Answer (score 6):

‘H’ represents a consonant sound, so we would expect ‘a hypothesis’, and that is what many say and write. However, where the stress in a word beginning with a sounded /h/ is on the second or subsequent syllable, some native speakers precede the word with ‘an’ rather than ‘a’, so you will also see and hear ‘an hypothesis’. But if you say and write ‘a hypothesis’, you will not be wrong.

Comment: I believe Americans who use *"an"* usually say *an ypothesis*. The 'h' in an unaccented syllable is often dropped after a consonant (which *"an"* ends with).

Comment: @PeterShor: Everyone using *an* will connect the two words and drop the h, I would say? *Anistoric, anypothesis, anonour, aneir, anour...*

Comment: @Cerberus: Your last three...there's no question, those words already start with a vowel not the glottal aspirate. No one says 'A hour'.

Comment: @Mitch: My point is they are pronounced the same way *if you use **an***. When you use *an*, the same pronunciation kicks in.