# Why are expressions like “gonna”, “wanna” and “shoulda” American English?

Tags: phrase-origin, contractions, transatlantic-differences, eye-dialect, weak-forms

As Etymonline suggests, the use of “a” meaning “have” in expressions like “should have” (*shoulda*), “could have” (*coulda*) and “would have” (*woulda*) were almost standard usage until the 17th century:

***[shoulda:](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=shoulda&allowed_in_frame=)***

> verbal phrase, 1902, representing casual (American) pronunciation of *should have*.
>
> - The use of *a* or 'a to represent a loose pronunciation of have as an auxiliary verb is attested from mid-14c. and was all but standard English until 17c. (also preserved in *coulda*, *woulda*).

Similar expressions like *gonna* (going to) and *wanna* (want to) have a less clear origin.

From [BBC.co.uk](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv165.shtml):

> - ***Wanna and gonna are frequently used in speech in informal colloquial English, particularly American English, instead of ‘want to’ and ‘going to’.*** You will also see them used in writing in quotes of direct speech to show the conversational pronunciation of ‘want to’ and ‘going to’.

*Gonna* appears to have similar earlier  usages in Scottish dialect (*ganna*, *gaumna*) but it is not clear if they are  related to the AmE ones:

***[wanna](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=wanna):***

> representing the casual pronunciation of ‘want to’, by 1896.

***[gonna](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/gonna?s=ts):***

> - attempt to represent the casual pronunciation of ‘going to’. In Scottish dialect, *ganna*, *gaunna* recorded from 1806.
> - Going to - Casually pronounced form : I'm gonna veg out tonight (1913+) - (Dictionary.com)

According to the above sources, the cited expressions appear to have  rather old origins, but they  emerged, or probably reemerged, around the end of the 19th century/beginning of the 20th century mainly in American English.

Questions:

- Is there evidence that the older original  usage of *shoulda*, *coulda* etc. actually influenced by assonance the later expressions like *gonna* and *wanna*, or have they unrelated origins?
- Is there a plausible reason why this “a” usage emerged  mainly in AmE?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60992/discussion-on-question-by-josh-why-are-expressions-like-gonna-wanna-and-sh).

Comment: Are you curious about when the sorta-standard nonstandard spellings _gonna, wanna, oughta,_ etc. first appeared? Or about the historical morphophonology of contracted prepositions?

Comment: @JohnLawler - when they first appeared in AmE is (more or less) clear. What is not clear is why and from where they came into common usage. Your second point.

Comment: @Josh: I still don't understand whether you're interested in the spellings or only the phonology. The spellings are irrelevant, afaics.

Comment: I'm afraid this is beyond my ability write a well phased and referenced answer, but after listening to a linguistics lecture series, I believe what is being applied here is the natural shortening of words relating to the "principle of least resistance". The evolution of language regularly has trailing words shortened or turned into suffixes. Also, B's become P's and vowel shifts upward reflect ease. "god bless you" became "good bye".  But why less so in GB ?  The written language and purposeful efforts slow the changes. The English might be more vested in maintaining their language as is.

Comment: In the southern Appalachians, The early Scots married into the Cherokee tribe, creating a bilingual and bi-cultural household that would later expand to become the dominant culture in the area for a century or more. As more Scots arrived, they married into these households and slowly gained control over trade, transportation, agriculture, and politics. They established schools, provided the teachers, established the Cherokee alphabet and published bilingual newspapers. That the local dialect should include old Scots idioms (and quite a bit of Cherokee influence) is hardly a surprise.

Comment: _Gonna_ and _wanna_ are used in Australian English.

Comment: For what its worth, central Scottish accents commonly use 'gonny/gaunae' for 'going to'. There are different ways of pronouncing it depending on regional and social accent/formality. Slightly less prevalent but still common is 'wanny/wannae' for want to'. To my ear the 'want to' variation more clearly retains a residual glottal stop which I assume arises for the same reasons that 'butter' is often pronounced 'bu'ur' or 'bu'er'.

Comment: Also, and I'm not sure this has a US equivalent 'dinnae' for 'do not'. 'should have' and 'would have' become 'would-ov' and 'should-ov' or 'would'v' and 'should'v' depending on emphasis. As noted these aren't *often* written/printed.

Comment: @Phil: I really don't think it was Scots that established the Cherokee alphabet. It was designed by somebody who had seen written English, but didn't know the correspondence between letters and sounds very well. Otherwise, I don't think they would have used *H* for me, *G* for nah, *Z* for no, *K* for tso, and *C* for tli.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll paste the relevant part of Postal and Pullum's (1978) article *Traces and the Description of English Complementizer Contraction* (*Linguistic Inquiry* 9:1):

[image]

Why American? That is very difficult to say! Rarely does someone have a good answer for why a specific sound change happened at a specific time for a specific speech community. We can only say what sorts of thing tend to happen, and what sort of things are rare. In this case, you see that the verb+clitic combination forms a trochee, and the unstressed syllable is the one that gets reduced. It would be interesting if a stressed syllable were the one to get reduced. In fact, we'd even start to question whether it was truly stressed.

Comment: Why do you think this is only American? I hear it from plenty of British and Australian speakers as well. Those guys also have "our" weak forms of other function words like *him, her, them*.

Comment: Thanks for providing interesting evidence.  Why this usage was, at least  originally, typical of AmE, unfortunately remains unclear.

Comment: At least in "Way Upstate NY," even *want+to* (i.e. not wanna) would have been something closer to "want tuh" (where "tuh" rhymes with "duh" and "uhhhhh"). So you'd wind up with things like "I normally wouldn't ask you to (*too*) go with me but...do you want to (*tuh*)?" Two forms for the same word. This form would very easily trend towards "wanna."

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a product of "phonetic realization" ([See: Stress (linguistics), Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(linguistics))). Similar examples are "dropping the 'G' in 'ing'" ("doin'" rather than "doing") , and the contraction "y'all". I have seen similar changes in stress when reading old Irish poetry, so I am not sure it is expressly an Americanism.

Additionally, in this article I found that "have" is cited as having a "weak form" in English ([SeeL Stress and vowel reduction in English, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_and_vowel_reduction_in_English).

> The vowel reduction in weak forms may be accompanied by other sound changes... The homonymy resulting from the use of some of the weak forms can lead to confusion in writing; the identity of the weak forms of have and of sometimes leads to misspellings such as "would of", "could of", etc. for would have, could have, etc.

It is reasonable to see that the confusion with the sound of "have" when said in a weak form is heard as "of", and may also be heard as "a". I.e. Should have --> should of --> should'a.

Answer (score -1):

Warning: speculative rather than definitive.

I wonder if this may have evolved.  You sometimes see **of** contracted to **o'** and occasionally "of" replaces "have" (not properly so, but still)...so:

Should have -> Should of -> Should o' -> Shoulda

Comment: Yup. Except that what happened was oral, not written. Writing comes after speech, and often doesn't change when speech does. In this case _should_ can take the infinitive _have_ to mark a past complement, even though (or, perhaps, because) the complement can't be inflected for tense. So _should have_ became a common phrase chunk, and of course got pronounced as one word, _should've_ /'ʃʊdəv/. This lost the final /v/ very easily, especially before a consonant, leaving /'ʃʊdə/. English words ending in /ə/ usually spell it with `A`, hence _shoulda_.

Answer (score -3):

This answer is also a bit speculative, I'm afraid. Another perceived Americanism is to remove the H from the beginning of words, such as *herb* → *'erb.* If you apply this to *should have* in order to form *should 'ave,* it's a short step from there to *shoulda.*

Comment: This doesn't cover **wanna** (want to)  nor **gonna** (going to), unless you can expand your answer.

Comment: In the song "Safety Dance", they sing "we can go where we *wanno",* which could be the missing link between *want 'o* and *wanna.*

Comment: "Herb" is a special case, not an example of a general difference between American and British English with regard to /h/-dropping.

Comment: @sumelic: No, it isn't. There are plenty of other words. *An 'otel, an 'istory* and so forth are pretty common in American English speech.

Comment: @konaya: A negligible amount of Americans write "an hotel", and even fewer say "an 'otel". As for "an 'istory", that sounds like Cockney, not a normal American accent. Why do you think these are "pretty common" in American English?

Comment: The Americans never removed the H from *herb*. We pronounce it the same way that we've pronounced it for the last 300 years.  The British don't know how to pronounce their own language; they started ***adding*** an H to *herb* some time in the 19th century. For all I know, they'll start adding an H to *hour* and *heir* soon.

Comment: @PeterShor it's called updating an old model. The British are very good at that sort of thing :) But I seem to recall that many Americans do erroneously say [**an historical event**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/usage/a-historic-event-or-an-historic-event) and someone once said: *In my speech, and I believe that of many* ***other Americans***, *an "h" in an unstressed syllable is either not pronounced or barely pronounced, except when it follows a vowel sound or a pause* Now, I wonder who [said](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/47092/44619) that...

Comment: @PeterShor do you consider *writing* "an historical event" to be acceptable in a formal paper, and would you recommend learners to say and write this form?

Comment: @Mari-Lou: ***If*** you speak a dialect where you naturally say *an 'istorical event* rather than *a historical event* (and there are a number of Americans who do, at least where I live), it is probably quite hard to avoid writing it. And I don't think it matters that much if you do write it; it's not seen as an inferior dialect. But it's much harder to learn this form, as you need to say *an 'istorical event* but *a history*. And there's utterly no reason to learn it; you should learn to speak the way most of us do.

Comment: @PeterShor  For an Italian speaker adding **an** before words that begin with H is not harder because in Italian the letter H is silent. They say "istorical" and "istory" as well as "otel" and "amburger" etc. Perhaps Americans should learn how to pronounce "herb(s)" with the letter H in front then :) Otherwise it should be spelled "erb" as in "erba" (Italian)