# is article "an" before the noun "hour" acceptable?

Tags: articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I use “a” versus “an” in front of a word beginning with the letter h?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/629/when-should-i-use-a-versus-an-in-front-of-a-word-beginning-with-the-letter-h)

I have seen many authors uses "an" before "hour" like "an hour" some times. Please consider the below excerpts.

> "How long is your break?", I shouted. A group of labourers sat under the banyan tree near the main campus building. "It's  two-thirty, lunch ended **an hour** ago."

and another one is below

> I would take his boat for **an hour**, and buy him tea and biscuits in return.

one more

> ' I won't take more than half **an hour**' I promised.

I learned from my teachers that the article "an" comes before vowels and not before consonants. Here "H" is consonant, still author uses the article "an" before "hour".

My question is, is this "an" before "hour" is acceptable? If yes can you explain why?

Comment: The choice is based on the first *sound* of the following word, not its first *letter*. "Hour" does not begin with a consonant *sound*, so the correct article is "an", just like with any other word beginning with a vowel *sound*. So this is not an exception, it's still the rule. But this question has been asked dozens of times before: it's [the top question in the FAQ tab](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=faq), and we even have a dedicated [blog post](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/articles-a-vs-an/). Please search the site before posting. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The first *sound*— not the first letter— is what determines which indefinite article to use. The spelling of a word is of no concern at all; if the first sound is a vowel sound, use *an*, and if the first sound is consonant, use *a*.

Since the *h* in *hour* is silent, *an hour* is correct, and *a hour* is incorrect. We also say

- an honor / an honour
- an heir
- an honest man

There are cases where the *h* may or may not be silent depending on the local dialect, as with *history*, *herb*, or *hotel*, in which case you should follow the local style.

Comment: I agree that _herb_ may be pronounced 'erb' (especially in the US), but have never heard the h-sound dropped from _historic_ or _hotel_. In the UK, they are often perversely rendered _an historic_ and _an hotel_ (not _an istoric_ and _an otel_).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The leading aspiration is dropped when people say *an historical event*.  It is in unstressed position next to the *i*, and just disappears.  This does not occur with *hotel*, whose *h* is much stronger than your *historical* ones. Anyone who actually pronounces an *h* after *an* has either misspoken or miswritten.

Comment: @tchrist: at http://editingandwritingservices.com/a-or-an-before-words-beginning-with-h/ is: Many peo­ple say, “An his­tor­i­cal occa­sion,” but “an his­tor­i­cal” isn’t used reg­u­larly in American English. Using “an” is com­mon, but not uni­ver­sally accepted by experts.>> Apparently, the question of whether _an historical_ is acceptable at all - however pronounced - hasn't been decided.

Comment: And at http://voices.yahoo.com/is-historic-2135385.html?cat=4 is: As the letter "h" **is now sounded** in English, the trend is away from "an historic" to "a historic". Some sources such as the American Heritage Dictionary say "an historic" is outdated. What is acceptable is often determined by general usage. (bolding mine)

Comment: You surely must mean American Eritage Dictionary (or America Heritage Dictionary) :-)

Answer (score 2):

Vowels and consonants are sounds, not letters, and it is the initial **sound** of a noun that determines whether the indefinite article preceding it is *a* or *an*. The initial sound of *hour* is /aʊ/, a vowel (well, actually, a diphthong), and not the consonant /h/.

Answer (score 0):

*Hour* is pronounced the same way as *our* - we say the *h* is unaspirated. The 'rule' is to use *an* rather than *a* before a word beginning with a vowel **sound**. Many people choose to ignore this rule with *historic* and, to a lesser degree I'd say, *hotel*. However, I always use *a historic* (*occasion*) and *a hotel*, as both of these words beginning with *h* are aspirated.

Comment: I think there is an element of prescriptivism here, and an element of the rule creating the (mis)behaviour because it is misunderstood.  So because they are told "an if and only before vowel" people (who want to appear erudite or upper class) train themselves and their children to the awkward "an hospital" and "an university", similar to people being told to say "X and I" and training themselves to use this even in object position (which had an original purpose of stylistic prescriptivism of putting yourself deprecatingly last).