# Why is there such confusion over a and an?

Tags: grammar

Recently while reading technical blog posts on the net I have started to see more frequently the incorrect use of 'an'.

My understanding from learning English as a child and English grammar in school is

- 'an' should be used before a word begining with a vowel sound.  This is most words that begin with a vowel and some that don't such as 'hour'.
- 'a' should be used in all other instances.

More and more I am seeing 'an JSON file' , 'an Yearling' and various other examples I haven't recorded.

Is there a reason for this trend (a change in education, a misunderstanding) or is it simply 2nd Language usage getting mixed up?

Comment: Why don't _you_ give the number of Google hits for "an JSON", "a JSON", "an yearling" and "a yearling"? And an Ngram comparison? These tools are admittedly not overly reliable, but might remove the unwanted 'in my opinion'.

Comment: Its just bad grammar. Tech bloggers, especially those from countries where english is not the native language, aren't exactly at the pinnacle of grammar correctness

Comment: @Somesh Mukherjee They probably forget to include traditionally required capital letters.

Comment: Yes, but that's not really relevant here.

Comment: You don't think standards of English are that important on this website? Its just not good enough in my opinion.[sic]

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee It's relevant to your comment above.

Comment: @Kriss and Edwin, oh for the love of Jesus. Just tell the man he forgot to use the capital E in "english". It's a simple slip, and acceptable when writing a comment; but not in questions or answers.

Comment: I am putting this on hold for two reasons. One, you are asking us to guess. We can't possibly know why someone's English is rubbish. Secondly and more importantly, this is a loaded question. People's English (French, math, geography) has been rubbish forever. In other words, please provide evidence that this is indeed a trend, otherwise it is just a recency illusion on your part. When you trade Byron for YouTube comments, "an yearling" comes with the territory.

Comment: People make mistakes about _a/an_ all the time. They always have; when to use an article is already problem enough for learners. Distinguishing _a_ from _an_ (as you say, a vowel sound is involved) requires one to distinguish between the ***sound*** of a word and its spelling. Both English learners who are improperly taught, and native speakers -- who are almost always improperly taught -- tend to confuse spelling with pronunciation. This is why it is and remains a problem. It's by no means a recent phenomenon. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recency_illusion.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth A very valid point! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Questions of *why* about language can rarely be answered definitively, but rules can be misapplied even by native speakers when dealing with unfamiliar words or constructions.

- The huge demand for English instruction is not always met with high quality instructors or textbooks. We have seen it asserted, for example, that the article choice is dependent on the head noun instead of the next word— thus *an green apple*. Incorrect or arbitrary rules such as these then get reinforced.
- Some people confuse the rule as applying to spelling as opposed to pronunciation, producing *an eucalyptus tree* or *a X-ray*. When you couple this with confusion over *y* and its use as a vowel, *an yearling* is explainable.
- Letters are not used to represent the same sounds in every language, and there is  additional trouble when transliteration is involved. I have heard *JSON* pronounced something like /iːʒoʊn/, which I can imagine could inspire someone to use *an*.
- Similarly, sometimes a word is substituted for a similar native word that would take a different article if it were an English word. In Spanglish you'll sometimes hear *an estudent*, instead of *a student*, because *student* is being partially substituted with the Spanish *estudiante*.
- In some cases, there are multiple accepted pronunciations which would alter the choice of article, e.g. *a SQL procedure* vs. *an SQL procedure*. Various *[H](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/629/when-should-i-use-a-versus-an-in-front-of-a-word-beginning-with-the-letter-h)* words like *hotel*, *historic*, etc. would vary by accent.
- Some people hypercorrect.