# Using 'a' or 'an' before a word that started with 'H'

Tags: grammar

What should we use before a word that started with 'H'?

'A' or 'An'? and why?

Sometime using 'a' seems right, sometimes using 'an' seems right, I am confused

Comment: This question has been asked, and answered, [46 times before](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/629?lq=1). It is indeed in the [Top 15 questions ever asked](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/629/). Two more questions in that Top 15 deal with *a* vs. *an*, and the answers to either apply here as well. We also have a [comprehensive blog post](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/articles-a-vs-an/). Please [use the search feature](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=a%20article%20h). It is also much faster than typing up an entire post.