# “An hilarious” vs. “a hilarious”

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

Which of these is correct? This is in the context of buying a surprise gift for someone and you think your gift is hilarious.

> I bought myself a hilarious one!

or

> I bought myself an hilarious one!

I’ve been saying both so many times that neither makes sense to me anymore.

Comment: See [When should I use “a” vs “an”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/)

Comment: They're both used (although *"a hilarious"* is more common).

Comment: Note particularly [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/632/2637) in the original question. Being British (and having listened to Jeremy Paxman for at least a couple of decades), I'm quite familiar with **an historic** (in writing, and in speech even where the /h/ is aspirated), but I've never read **an hilarious**, and never heard it except in Cockney-style aitch-dropping speech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [LDOCE](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/hilarious), the pronunciation of the word is: `/hı'leəriəs -'ler-/` and that `/h/` is actually pronounced, and is NOT silent like the `h` in the word "*hour*". So you must use the indefinite article ***a***, rather than ***an***, because what you hear at the beginning of the word, is a consonant sound, rather than a vowel one.

> *a hilarious story*

---

**Note:** This is unrelated to your example, but it's worth mentioning: I've seen "*a HTC phone*" on Irish/British newspapers several times, and the first time, I just blamed the editors for not being careful with proofreading things before publishing, and it took me a bit of time to recognize that the way they'd say that letter in British English is `/heıtʃ/`, that actually contains that /h/ in the beginning, where in American English that would be "*an HTC phone*"!

Comment: Re: the HTC phone --It seems like it should be the other way around.

Comment: Whooops! How did I make that mistake?! Thanks @ChrisSunami. Edited it. (: