# Is hilarious pronounced /hɪˈlɛriəs/?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling, dictionaries, north-american-english, fast-speech-rules, stress-reduction

For the word [hilarious](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/hilarious?q=Hilarious), the pronunciation transcription in the Oxford Advanced American Dictionary is /hɪˈlɛriəs/ but if I click on the speaker icon, I hear /həˈlɛriəs/. Am I listening to it wrong or are Oxford pronunciations not 100% consistent?

Answer (score 3):

The difference between /ɪ/ and /ə/ in unaccented syllables is of very little importance in English. There are some people who use /ə/ instead of /ɪ/ in unaccented syllables (this is called the [weak vowel merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_close_front_vowels#Weak_vowel_merger)). Presumably, the speaker Oxford used had this merger.

More specifically, there are some people who use /ə/ for the first syllables of both *hilarious* and *malarious*, and some people who pronounce *hilarious* with /ɪ/ and *malarious* with /ə/.  Native English speakers typically pay very little attention to the quality of vowels in completely unaccented syllables.

Comment: Once a vowel is unstressed, it's centralized almost automatically, since central vowels constitute the largest space for making vowels that don't contrast. The big contrasts are in front and back vowels, which have very crowded spaces. If you don't need to stress, you don't need to contrast, and that squirts out a centralized epenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

## phonemic /ə/ ≠ phonetic [ə]

I realize this may well strike you as an outrageous proposition, but your
fundamental mistake lies in somehow believing that dictionaries contain actual **phonetic**
transcriptions. They do not. They contain **phonemic** transcription, which
means that /ə/ **does not *necessarily*** mean [ə]. Often it does not.

Here’s where you’ve gone wrong. Dictionaries never contain that phonetic
information. They provide only enough phonemic information for **native
speakers** to figure out how to say something in their own accents based on
whatever phonological rules apply there.

Per [the Wikipedia article on ə](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid_central_vowel):

> The symbol ⟨ə⟩ is often used for any unstressed obscure vowel, regardless
> of its precise quality. For instance, the English vowel transcribed ⟨ə⟩ is
> a central unrounded vowel that can be close-mid [ɘ], mid [ə] or open-mid
> [ɜ], depending on the environment.

Notice that it can represent **any** obscure vowel, one whose precise
quality is immaterial.

Phonemically, /ə/ normally represents a set of centralized vowels of
**indistinct** character, particularly when it is reduced and neutralized
in unstressed syllables in fluent connected speech.  Vowel reduction in
unstressed syllables varies significantly by region, accent, register,
speaker, and utterance.

Just as the abstract /r/ phoneme can for example represent [ɹ], [ɻ], [ɻʷ],
or [ɾ] yet very rarely ever [r], so too does the abstract /ə/ phoneme
represent a wide range of possible allophones including [ʌ], [ɵ], [ɘ],
[ə], [ɜ], [ɛ], [ɪ], [ɨ], [ɪ̈], [ɨ̞], [i], and probably many more.

So even though these may all well sound *hilarious* to me but not to you,
**pronunciations like [hɪˈleɹɪjəs] and [hɨˈlɛɹjəs] and even [əˈlæɾiəs]** are
all not only the very same word, they also represent perfectly normal
allophonic realizations of the very same underlying phonemes.

See also [the section covering the weak vowel merger in the Wikipedia article on the phonological history of the English close front vowels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_close_front_vowels#Developments_involving_weak_vowels).

Comment: [Strangely related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/187634/2085).