# Is it "a honor" or "an honor"? is h silent in this word in American English?

Tags: indefinite-articles, silent-letters

I read a tweet of President Obama:

> An honor to address the Coast Guard class of 2015. Confident they'll help us meet big challenges like climate change.

Is `h`  a silent letter in this word in American English?

Comment: The "h" is silent.  But both "a" or "an" can be used.  It would be a bit odd to hear "a honor", but some people do this for emphasis.

Comment: The "h" is *mostly* silent.  There is often a hint of an "h" sound in words like "honor", but it is still treated as a vowel sound.

Comment: @HotLicks I have never heard any hint of an h in _honour_ as spoken by any native speaker. Of some people do add in a bit of aitchiness, I suspect it's because of the spelling.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - It's definitely subtle.

Comment: @HotLicks I suspect it's not actually there—or rather, that the likelihood of there being any actual, phonetic aspiration in _honour_ is about the same as in _on a_ (can't think of a pair that rhymes properly in AmE apart from _on her_, which just moves the issue to the next syllable).

Comment: @Hot Licks: I think you're mistaken. Most people no longer aspirate *where, whom*, etc. at all - but some still do, and I suppose a few of those will have reduced it to a "hint". But I don't think there's any corresponding "residual aspirate" in words like *honour*. Or even in ***historical***, come to that - and that's one of the few "potentially silent aitch" words where [some real purists](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/640/2637) say ***an historical event*** is correct even though it's *also* correct to enunciate the aitch.

Comment: @HotLicks, there's no h in the pronunciation of "honor".  Not even a hint.

Comment: @GregLee - Whatever you say.

Comment: @HotLicks, I should have explained.  The difference between an h-beginning word and a vowel-beginning word is categorical -- it's not a matter of degree.  Some phonetic differences are matters of degree, but not this one.  And we know that because this difference conditions the phonemic difference between forms of the article /a/ and /an/.  Non-phonemic differences cannot condition phonemic differences.

Comment: Whatever you say.  Been speaking English for 60-odd years, but I suppose you know better.

Comment: Hot Licks, where do you live? I'm sure you know what you're talking about, but here in New York, no one pronounces the h in honor. Maybe it's a localized thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the H in hono(u)r is silent in both American and British English.

Sources: [one](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/british/honor), [two](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/honor_1), [three](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/honour_1).