# Is “an historical” correct?

Tags: pronunciation, articles, stress, fast-speech-rules, sandhi

Why do some people say or write *an historical* but not *an ham sandwich* or *an hint*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use "a" versus "an" in front of a word beginning with the letter h?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/629/when-should-i-use-a-versus-an-in-front-of-a-word-beginning-with-the-letter-h)