# "An" or "A" with acronyms which sound like they start with a vowel?

Tags: grammar, acronyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you use “a” or “an” before acronyms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms)

Should you use "a"n or "a" with acronyms which sound like they start with a vowel when read literally?

...is covered in an FAQ located at....

or

...is covered in a FAQ located at...

When I read the sentence I pronounce eff-eh-queue but I'm not sure if most people do that.

Comment: See here for pronunciation of FAQ: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4165/what-is-the-commonly-accepted-pronunciation-of-faq