# "A" vs. "An" in writing vs. pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation, articles

When starting a word with a vowel, the preceding "a" becomes an "an". I often find that when writing words that start with letter "N" or "M", I will pronounce them "EN", "EM", etc. (This is because in programming, letters are often pronounced in certain terms.)

So, when writing a question on SO, do I write "an NSString" or, "a NSString"?

Comment: A borderline dupe of [An or A with acronyms which sound like they start with a vowel?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4403/), [an SQA or a SQA?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2736/), and [Do you use “a” or “an” before acronyms?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/). I am inclined to vote to close.

Comment: I've added my close vote as well, although I think Dusty's answer below is better than those received by either of the two questions this duplicates.

Comment: @Martha: Dusty's answer will survive. `Closed` doesn't mean "off-topic" or "will be deleted", it simply means "not accepting further answers". See [this meta question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/381/).

Comment: This falls under "borderline dupe". While the topic of the question is the same, the question itself is different. Close? Puleez.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The choice of `a` vs. `an` is actually based on the phonetics of the start of a word, not the orthographic representation.  This is why you say things like `an honorable solider` (the h is silent, so phonetically it begins with the vowel sound).  Similarly, you would say `a one-eyed pirate` as `one` phonetically begins with the `w` sound.

So in the case of your example, it would be `an NSString` since phonetically it's `en-es-string`.