# "a" or "an" in this situation?

Tags: word-choice, articles, indefinite-articles

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [“A” vs. “An” in writing vs. pronunciation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4957/a-vs-an-in-writing-vs-pronunciation)
>   [Use of “a” versus “an”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/use-of-a-versus-an)

I know that "an" should be used when a word is followed by a noun that starts with a vowel.

But what about a numerical value that isn't formally written out and used as an adjective?
Such as "a 8x8 grid" is it that, or "an 8x8 grid" ?

I've received some disagreements on this in the past, so I'd just like some clearing up. Any reference to formal rules would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

"A" vs. "an" doesn't depend on spelling; it depends on pronunciation. 8 begins with a vowel sound so, 'an' is appropriate.

Comment: Ah, so that's why you say "an hour ago" instead of "a hour ago" ?

Comment: @Johaness: Right! :)

Comment: Yep, dropped 'h's at the beginning of the word lead to the word's beginning with a vowel sound, and so the indefinite article changing.  Witness the UK pronunciation of the article with 'herb' ('h' not dropped), *a herb, a herbalist*, vs. the US pronunciation ('h' dropped), *an herb, an herbalist*.