# Why "an FT op-ed"

Tags: articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“A” vs. “An” in writing vs. pronunciation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4957/a-vs-an-in-writing-vs-pronunciation)

In an article in [The Economist](http://www.economist.com/blogs/easternapproaches/2011/11/polands-appeal-germany), it is written "That was raised in an FT op-ed...". Why is it "an FT op-ed" and not "a FT op-ed"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An abbreviation or initialism takes the article appropriate to its pronunciation. The author intends it to be said "eff-tee," so it takes the "an" rather than the "a."

Answer (score 4):

The choice of *a/an* depends on how the subsequent word is pronounced, not how it is spelled. FT is pronounced "ef tee" [ɛf ti]; it begins with a vowel sound, and therefore the correct article is "an".