# Is "an s-t-r-e-e-t" correct?

Tags: grammar, articles

For example, is the following sentence grammatically correct in terms of the usage of the article?

- There was an s-t-r-e-e-t in London.

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4957/a-vs-an-in-writing-vs-pronunciation/4958

Comment: Assuming you pronounce the "s-t-r-e-e-t" "ess-tee-..." then yes.