# How to pronounce FAQ? ˈɛfˈeɪˈkyu or fæk?

Tags: pronunciation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the commonly accepted pronunciation of FAQ?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4165/what-is-the-commonly-accepted-pronunciation-of-faq)

FAQ stands for Frequently Asked Questions. I checked some dictionaries, they list both of the pronunciations. So I'm confused. What is the common way to pronounce FAQ?

Comment: I pronounce it FAQ with the a as in asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In more than 20 years of Internet and BBS usage I have only ever heard FAQ pronounced "fack" (fæk), at least in American English.

Comment: Hmm — I’ve only ever heard it read letter-by-letter!  Possibly I associate with less hardcore internet people than you do.

Comment: American English seems to prefer reading acronyms out as words, British English prefers spelling them out. As a Brit, I've heard /fæk/ maybe twice ever (also in a couple of decades of being online). Here in Britain, it would always be /ˈɛfˈeɪˈkyu/

Answer (score 3):

Both are common, or they wouldn't be listed in the dictionary.  Although most dictionaries give the (slightly?) more prevalent pronunciation first (same goes for spelling, if more than one variation exists).

Now to your unstated question, "Which one should I use?": use the one you like better.  Or the one that is more common among your colleagues or friends, whichever applies to your circumstances.

Comment: +10, if I could.  This is the answer to so many “pronunciation varies” questions…

Comment: +1 for anti-gregarious recommendation as well.