# Is it "a uniform" or "an uniform"?

Tags: grammaticality, articles, indefinite-articles

On a Physics specification, it says:

> 6.7 Know how to use two permanent magnets to produce a uniform magnetic field pattern.

Isn't it "produce *an* uniform magnetic field", or is the existing "produce *a* uniform magnetic field pattern" correct?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The word *uniform* begins with a [palatal approximant /j/](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatal_approximant). The palatal approximant is a consonantal sound, even though the letter itself is a vowel. Since we use the pronunciation of the word following the article to determine whether we use "a" or "an", and because it is pronounced starting with a consonant, we use "a". Thus, the original sentence is correct.

---

Just for the sake of completeness, the letter "u" can also have a vowel sound, such as in the word "umbrella", which begins with an [open-mid back unrounded vowel /ʌ/](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_back_unrounded_vowel).

Answer (score 25):

The rule of placing *an* before a vowel is actually to place *an* before a **vowel sound**. Therefore, because *uniform* is pronounced with a "y" sound (/ˈjuːnɪfɔːm/), which is not a vowel sound, it takes an *a* before it.

Answer (score 9):

I would use "a uniform", because *uniform*, although it is *spelled* with an initial vowel, is *pronounced* as beginning with a "y" sound.  Compare, on the other side of the coin, "an honor" where, although h is a consonant, the word is pronounced as though starting with a vowel (at least, in my part of the world...)

Answer (score 7):

Whether you use *a* or *an* is entirely decided by the **sound** of the following word, and doesn't necessarily have anything to do with the **spelling** of the following word. Words like *uniform* or *user* are pronounced with an initial "y" sound (a palatal glide), and so it's correct to say *a uniform, a user*. Saying *an uniform, an user* is incorrect.