# A becomes an before a word beginning with a vowel, does this apply to u?

Tags: word-choice, articles, indefinite-articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use of “a” versus “an”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/use-of-a-versus-an)
>   [Is it “a uniform” or “an uniform”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/is-it-a-uniform-or-an-uniform)

In spoken English we do say:

> He is *an* unhappy person

But I never hear anyone say:

> He has *an* user account

I have a lot of exposure to overseas students in Australia, and I am thinking that it is because of textbooks and lack of spoken English that this is now becoming a trend.

Can anyone please tell me if this is correct or not?

It makes me so mad I want to ride away on an unicorn.

Comment: I mention the specific case "user" in my answer to the question that Tsuyoshi Ito has linked to. Also see my answer at http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/grammar-check-needed-on-one-line-of-a-syllabus/4701#4701 for a similar scenario.