# Does a word that starts with a vowel letter start with a vowel sound?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, fast-speech-rules, sandhi

I'm currently learning about consonant to vowel linking, and I'm wondering if it's safe to assume that most words (if not all?) that start with a vowel letter (a, e, i, o, u) will also start with a vowel sound.

Knowing this information will help me quickly identify whether a word starts with a vowel sound. Then, I can check the ending sound of the previous word to see where consonant-to-vowel linking is required.

Comment: It's not a safe assumption. Many words starting with the letters "u" or "eu" start with the consonant sound /j/; see [Is it “a uniform” or “an uniform”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4700)

Comment: @sumelic yes  but /j/in those words  is a glide or semi-vowel, it's very much like a vowel; which is why some people use, or have used, *an* before them, as in *an university*.

Comment: @Clare: phonetically it is like a vowel, but an English language learner should be careful to avoid thinking of it as a vowel sound for the purposes of English phonological rules. "An university" is non-standard in modern English and I find it hard to think of a situation in which it would benefit a non-native speaker to use this instead of "a university".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best rule in English is that you should ignore spelling for purposes of pronunciation and ignore pronunciation for purposes of spelling, as these two things each have their own separate stories. You must learn each one separately by rote, not attempt to infer one from the other.

Sandhi effects have nothing to do with letters. They are purely phonologic in origin, so only sounds count.

So *eunuchs, Unix, Europe, Ulysses, eustachian, Oaxaca* all begin with consonants, while *honor, honest, hour, huerta, our, umbrella, ylem, Ysidro* all begin with vowels.  Words like *herbal* and *historical* can vary.

And not all sandhi effects are the same, either. Just because we use the same pronunciation for *an* in both *an apple* and *an eel* doesn’t mean we use the same pronunciation of *the* in both *the apple* and *the eel*; with *the eel*, there is an extra glottal stop after /ði/, so /ðiʔˈil/.

Comment: I use a *loʔa* glottal stops (unlike some Northerners on this side of the pond, who'd say *lorra* there), but I wouldn't include one in *the eel*. I just lengthen the ***ee*** in contexts like that, but if I *imagine* other Brits using a glottal stop, it seems to me they'd probably also switch the /i/ to a schwa.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Even though I'm American, I agree; I would say [ðəʔˈiɫ]. If I add a glottal stop, I don't see any reason to use /ði/ rather than /ðə/

Comment: @PeterShor How do you otherwise stop the two instances of /i/ from fusing? By adding a glide like /ðiˈjil/ ?

Comment: I can imagine others introducing a more pronounced "glide", but for me it's just an almost imperceptible lengthening of the "one-and-only" vowel.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Right, so you essentially fuse and/or lengthen.

Comment: Exactly. So if you were a *Spanish* waiter, and thus couldn't hear the difference between /v/ and /b/, the only way to know whether I'd said *I'll have the eel pie* or *I'll have the veal pie* would be that ***the** = /ði/* in the first case, but /ðə/ in the second.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Need to look each word to verify pronunciation, for example, the o in opossum is silent and pronounced "possom."  Per Cambridge Dictionary, Webster, and traditionary sources:​ /əˈpɑs·əm/ short form possum, US ​ /ˈpɑs·əm/

Comment: But that's a rare case. Even a lot of native speakers are confused about the pronunciation of *opossum*, and it is not pronounced as starting with a P-sound by everyone.

Comment: @Clare, only Irish opossums prefer to have their species name pronounced that way.

Comment: "the o in opossum is silent". Not so. Even the sources you cite do not give a pronunciation of "opossum" with silent o. The two-syllable pronunciation you cite is of "possum", which is a different word.