# Why do you say "Do you have “a” euro?" Rather than "an" Euro?

Tags: word-choice, pronunciation, indefinite-articles

> Do you have ***a*** euro?

I saw the above sentence and do not understand why you say "a" instead of "an"?

You say *Do you have "an" umbrella?*, but *Do you have "a" pound*?

Comment: Ignore the spelling - it's the *pronunciation* that matters. The first phonetic element in a ***euro*** is the same as in a ***young man***.

Comment: Also this question: [Is it “a uniform” or “an uniform”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/is-it-a-uniform-or-an-uniform)

Comment: It's a uniform. For the reasons I mentioned below

Answer (score 0):

Because "U" is here a semi- vowel/ semi - consonant. The same way "w" is a semi- vowel. When they stand at the beginning of a word, they operate as virtual consonants, so the "an" -
which is only used for words whose first sound is a vowel-  doesn't work.

A few words to exemplify this: union, university, yahoo, yellowish, yell, winner, wimp, walk, yen.

You would use "a" and not "an" with these words.

Comment: Wow! Now, I will look up semi-vowels and semi - consonant.  Never heard of them.  Thank you

Comment: I don't understand actually, because euro starts with an e, though it is silent.  Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @Maria: the use of "a" and "an" has nothing to do with how a word is spelled. It is based purely on pronunciation.

Comment: @sumelic Sadly not true. Some persist in using _an_ before an aspirated _hotel_, etc.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I'm not sure how that relates to spelling. It can be explained as the use of "an" before /h/ in an unstressed syllable.

Comment: @sumelic Some don't say 'an hotel'. The choice of 'an' may have nothing to do with spelling, but is not based purely on pronunciation.

Comment: why would you give examples with "w" like "winner", "wimp", "walk"? I think we use "a" before them, so it doesn't look like any exception

Comment: It's not an exception, that was my whole point -- that you use use "a" before them because they work as consonants at the beginning of a word