# Why does "an universe" sound so wrong?

Tags: grammaticality

I just ran across the phrase "an universe where" in a book, and my mind is telling me that it should be "a universe where."  It just *sounds wrong.*

But... you're supposed to put "a" when the next word starts with a consonant, and "an" where the next word starts with a vowel. U is definitely a vowel.  So why does this phrase sound so wrong?

Comment: Because _an_ only goes before vowels, and _universe_ starts with the consonant /y/, so it should be _a_. Real language rules, like the alternation between _a_ and _an_, refer to **Sounds**, not spelling. U is only a vowel in spelling.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use "a" vs "an"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/when-should-i-use-a-vs-an)

Comment: Also: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/4700/191178

Comment: Some Welsh people might very well say 'an ooniverse' because that regional dialect can ignore the initial 'y' sound of 'u'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although we are often taught that it is vowels and consonants that govern the ‘a’ or ‘an’ rule, it is actually the sound itself. That is, vowel sounds are preceded by 'an' and consonant sounds by ‘a’. In this case universe has a consonant (Y) sound.

Comment: Hello, Clare. Please help to avoid bloat on the site by checking for obvious duplicates before rushing to answer. In any case, there are cases like 'an historian', 'an hotel' where the issue is not so simple. Again, already well covered.

Comment: Vowels and consonants **are** sounds. Letters don't make sounds.