# "A heroic" or "An heroic"?

Tags: grammaticality, indefinite-articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“A historic…” or “An historic…”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/629/a-historic-or-an-historic)

I have heard and read this combination both ways:

```
It was a heroic act.

It was an heroic act.
```

Personally, I pronounce the "h", and believe that "a" is correct. I find that it sounds incorrect to use "an" and pronounce "heroic" without the "h."

Are both acceptable or is there one that is correct?

(Inspired by [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8181/does-one-use-a-or-an-before-the-word-x-ray).)