# "An RPG" or "a RPG"?

Tags: word-choice, pronunciation, articles, indefinite-articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I use “a” vs “an”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/when-should-i-use-a-vs-an/)
>   [Do you use “a” or “an” before acronyms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms)
>   [Does one use 'a' or 'an' before the word X-Ray?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8181/does-one-use-a-or-an-before-the-word-x-ray)

Hello people, English is not my primary language, so it is just natural I make such basic questions...

Is it correct to say "An RPG" (where RPG could be the common "Role-Playing Game" term), or do I have to say "A RPG", without the "n"? Considering RPG does not begin with a vowel... yet, it sounds like it does.