# Should I say "a LSM-tree" or "an LSM-tree"?

Tags: american-english, academic-writing

The "LSM-tree" is an acronym term for "Log-Structured Merge Tree".

I wrote "a LSM-tree", but Grammarly keeps reminding me it should be "an LSM-tree".

What is the reason for this?

Comment: indefinite article usage depends on the _sound_ of the next phoneme. "L" sounds like "ell", so it's _an_ in this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do you use "a" or "an" before acronyms / initialisms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms-initialisms) //////////////////// also [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11505/an-rpg-or-a-rpg)

Comment: @GEdgar raises a valid point...do _you_ pronounce it LSM, or "Lassum"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on whether *LSM* starts with a vowel sound, not on whether it starts wilth an actual vowel.

If you pronounce *LSM* like "ell ess emm" then use *an* with it.  But if you use some pronunciation like "lassum" then use *a* with it.