# A SVG or An SVG

Tags: word-choice, american-english

Which one is correct `A SVG` or `An SVG`?

P.S. A/An SVG is a type if image file.

Comment: see https://english.stackexchange.com/a/563727/9368 and https://english.stackexchange.com/q/1016/9368

Comment: It starts with a vowel sound (_**e**ss_), so use *an*.