# a LAN vs an LAN

Tags: abbreviations, indefinite-articles

LAN is the abbreviation for local area network. According to dictionaries, it has two variants of the pronunciation: [læn] and [ˌeleɪˈen]. Does it mean we can write both "a LAN" and "an LAN"? Thanks!

Comment: TLDR; yes, both are correct because there is a vowel pronunciation and a consonant pronunciation.

Comment: FWIW, I never use 'an' for this; if I don't pronounce it as /læn/, I'll fully expand it to "local area network", neither of which is appropriately written with 'an'.

Comment: See also https://english.stackexchange.com/a/563727/9368

Comment: I've seldom/never heard it pronounced L - A - N (dictionaries don't always reflect current usage especially in technical subcultures). But spell it how you pronounce it, or how you see it commonly done.