# "An RV" or "a RV"?

Tags: acronyms, indefinite-articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you use “a” or “an” before acronyms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms)

I am writing about Random Variables, which I am abbreviating to RV. Should I write 'an RV' (an Arr-Vee) or 'a RV' (a Random Variable)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This depends entirely on how you expect people to read the letters `RV`. If you expect them to say "random variable" every time, then use *a RV*. If you expect that they'll pronounce the letter names, use *an RV*. Personally, I would lean towards the latter.

That's because [the choice of *a* or *an* is determined entirely by pronunciation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8181/does-one-use-a-or-an-before-the-word-x-ray).

Answer (score 4):

When someone reads "RV" aloud, they will say "Arr-Vee", not "random variable"; so 'an' is correct.

Answer (score 1):

"An RV".  It's whether it would be pronounced with a vowel sound that controls, and what you would actually say rather than the expansion.

Answer (score 1):

"That there's an RV, Clark." - Cousin Eddie, Christmas Vacation

I think cousin Eddie got it right, as did @JSBangs.

Comment: Cousin Eddie is amazing, driving and inhabiting a random variable!