# Why do we write 'He has an MA' and not ' a MA' even though MA does not begin with a vowel? Can anybody give me anymore examples like it?

Tags: indefinite-articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you use “a” or “an” before acronyms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms)

Why do we write 'He has an MA' and not ' a MA' even though MA does not begin with a vowel? Can anybody give me anymore examples like it?

Comment: Dear nicholas, at 1.4k rep I would expect you to search the site first. This question gets asked [over](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms) and [over](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14772/an-rv-or-a-rv) and [over](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14429/is-it-a-ssd-or-an-ssd) and [over](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2736/an-sqa-or-a-sqa) and [over](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5265/an-sql-server-database-schema-or-a-sql-server-database-schema) again. (And I could go on, but I've run out of space.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We write "an MA" rather than "a MA" because the choice of article is decided by pronunciation and "M" is pronounced with an initial vowel sound.

Other examples:

- an FTP transfer
- an HMRC office
- an L-plate
- an MOT test
- an NCP car-park
- an RAC van
- an SSD device
- an X-Ray image
- an MSc in Chemistry

Comment: I like your answer because you get a point in 1,5 lines. If you could give an example, it would be perfect. (Don't get me wrong, it's not bad as it is now, I just like to be super-explicit ahah).

Comment: Gets tricky with SQL - depends if your pronounce it as ess-queue-ell or sequel