# "A" or "an" in front of a number that can be read in two ways

Tags: grammaticality

Consider the following sentence.

We are selling ___ 1,800 sq ft office.

I would write *an*, because I say *eighteen hundred*.
But someone else would say *a*, because they say *one thousand eight hundred*.

For *2,000* it's easier, because it's always *two thousand*.

For *2,100* it can again be *twenty one hundred*, or *two thousand one hundred*.

So what is grammatically correct, what do I write so that I don't confuse my readers?

Comment: "We are selling an office which is 1,800 sq ft in size." avoids the problem altogether.

Comment: Most in the US would read it as "eighteen hundred".

Comment: It is not really a matter of grammar, or even spelling.  It is the sort of thing where a public tog would have its own policy (a 'style guide').  Many people mentally 'hear' what they are reading, and so for them 'a 1,800 sq ft office' sets up a 'discord' between what they see and what they 'hear'.  It need not be a problem.  But a useful rule of thumb is to find a way of avoiding the dilemma altogether.  For example, "for sale:  1,800 sq ft office"; or "we are selling an office of 1,800 sq ft"; or we are selling 1,800 sq ft of office space"  ...

Comment: I would likely choose *a* here on the understanding that the standard form is "one thousand, eight hundred," then pronounce it "an eighteen hundred" when I read it aloud.

Comment: @Ian MacDonald offers the best solution, a rewrite; this won't get anyone tied up in knots. Grammaticality isn't involved; neither variant  violates any rule of grammar. But Gricean Maxims require that you take pains to avoid any source of confusion / disorderliness (!), and if you want to honour them fully, you can't use either 'a' or 'an' here (some group will be discomfited) and using 'a/an' is not as concise as a rephrase.

Comment: As in *["An SQL Server database schema" or "a SQL Server database schema"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5265/an-sql-server-database-schema-or-a-sql-server-database-schema)*, *[Is it supposed to be a HTML or an HTML](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25742)*, *[“An RV” or “a RV”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14772/)* and so on, either form is valid, so don't get too worked up over it, or just reword the sentence as elsewhere suggested.