# Why shouldn't we say "an user"?

Tags: articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I use “a” vs “an”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/when-should-i-use-a-vs-an)
>   [Does one use 'a' or 'an' before the word X-Ray?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8181/does-one-use-a-or-an-before-the-word-x-ray)

As far as I understood, you prefix "an" instead of "a" before any proceeding word starting with a vowel when you wish to speak about an object (there's probably a correct term for this), but ie. a towel, a tree etc.

So why is it so common to say "**a** user clicked this" or "please enter **a** username" and not "an" instead of "a" like "an umbrella"?