# Using `an` before consonants

Tags: indefinite-articles, consonants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why shouldn't we say “an user”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41561/why-shouldnt-we-say-an-user)

I've personally seen the indefinite article `an` coming before consonants in many places whereas I think that should be a mistake.
I'm wondering if that's the case or using `an` before consonants is grammatically a mistake?
For example consider this:

> Insert an user into the database.

Taken from [Worepress Trac](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/user.php) (line `1028`).

Comment: Mistakes and typos happen.