# What indefinite article ("a" or "an") should be used before "x"

Tags: pronunciation, indefinite-articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does one use 'a' or 'an' before the word X-Ray?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8181/does-one-use-a-or-an-before-the-word-x-ray)

I understand that the decision between "a" and "an" is generally based on what vowel sound the following word begins with.

In the case of "x" I am not sure, it could be either:

- An ehcks
- A ecks