# What article do we use before a symbol? Is it "an @" or "a @"?

Tags: indefinite-articles

I got a question when reading this text:

> The name of the decorator should be prepended with an @ symbol.

Should we write "a @ symbol" or "an @ symbol"? As "@" is in fact "at", I would think "an" should be used to avoid the coexistence of two vowels one after the other.

More generally, what is the general rule to know if we have to write "a" or "an" before other symbols like "€", etc.? Is it based on how the symbol is read?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do you use "a" or "an" before acronyms?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms) Also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8181/does-one-use-a-or-an-before-the-word-x-ray/8183#8183

Comment: @Neeku Not really a duplicate of those two. They deal with acronyms, which are at least _letters_, and as such are expected to represent distinct sounds. Symbols are slightly different in that they _might_ correspond to a conventional pronunciation, or they might not.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet If you read through all the answers in those links, you'll find out that they say you'll decide on using `a/an` based on the first sound you hear pronouncing the word, so it doesn't matter if it's an acronym or a noun or whatever, **because the choice of a or an is determined entirely by pronunciation**.

Comment: @Neeku Tell me, then, if it’s _a ❦_ or _an ❦_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Tell me its name and I'll tell you. "A cherry" if that's one!

Comment: @Neeku That’s the whole point. It doesn’t have a conventional name, which is what makes this a non-duplicate.

Comment: On the other hand, the symbols the OP asks about, @ and € _do_ have a conventional pronunciation, so it would follow that it is _an @_ and _a €_. For symbols without a conventional pronunciation, I would use _a_, but I don;t really have any good argument to back that up...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The flag is approved as *helpful*. The question here is NOT about `How to pronounce symbols in English?`, but `How to decide on using *a* or *an*?`, and the answer is *based on pronunciation* which is already explained, and as @oerkelens said, we know the pronunciation of those symbols. (:

Comment: Except that @ can be called [*commercial at*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/@).

Comment: @AndrewLeach - The OP mentions a quote about decorators in a programming environment. The common pronunciation of @ in that environment is certainly _at_. Although, surely, it can also be dubbed _monkey tail_ or _squiggly thingee_ or any of the other inventions of people that found themselves in need of reading their e-mail address out loud, in the context of formal writing about a programming language, I would assume it safe to stick with _at_.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I use "a" vs "an"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/when-should-i-use-a-vs-an)

Comment: [You do not have a doubt.  You merely have a question.](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2429/2085)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The article to use does indeed depend on how you pronounce the symbol when speaking out loud.

Since *@* is usually read out loud as ‘at’ /æt/ in English, it takes the prevocalic article *an*, as you surmise. (It can also be called the *commercial at*, but that is rarer, and I would not write *a @* unless I’d already specified that it was intended to be pronounced as ‘commercial at’ in the context.)

The symbol *€* would most commonly be read as ‘euro sign’, which means it begins with a (consonantal) [j] sound, and would thus take the preconsonantal article *a*.

Difficulties arise when you reach symbols that either have multiple conventional pronounced counterparts or no conventional pronounced counterparts at all.

The symbol *#* is a good example of the former: it is varyingly called a *number sign*, a *pound sign*, and a *hash* (all of which begin with a consonant, indicating *a #*), but also an *octothorpe* (which would indicate *an #*). As such, you could write either *a #* or *an #* and be ‘correct’—but you’ll likely find readers who stumble at either, because they’re used to calling the symbol by a name that doesn’t fit the article you choose to use. Another example is the ornamental symbol ❦ whose Unicode name is *floral heart*, but which is traditionally called either an *Aldus leaf* after the Italian Renaissance printer [Aldus Manutius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldus_Manutius) or a *fleuron*. The latter is technically a more generic term that describes the function, rather than the shape, of the character, and a few other symbols are also used as fleurons (mostly *florettes*, of which only ❀ and ❁ are encoded in Unicode); but the Aldus leaf is by far the commonest, and *fleuron* is usually synonymous with *Aldus leaf*—or indeed *floral heart*.

The latter group is rather larger and contains an enormous array of shapes and forms:

- letter-based symbols like ℳ (Unicode name *script capital m*, no known traditional name that I’m aware of)
- ambiguous cases like ᐄ (it could be letter-based U+1404 *Canadian Syllabics ii*, or it could be mathematical U+29CA *triangle with dot above*. Neither has any widely known traditional reading)
- purely graphical forms like ╊ (U+254A *box drawings left light and right vertical heavy*—definitely no common name for such cases)
- CJK glyphs in general—would you, for example, write *a 囊* because the character 囊 is pronounced *náng* in Mandarin, but *an 昂* because the character 昂 is pronounced *áng*?
  (And what if the symbol is actually quoted in a Cantonese context, where it’s pronounced *ngòhng*?)

I have never seen any style guide or guidelines mention this latter case at all. In the absence of a conventional pronunciation, there is no real way of deciding what article to use. In the rare instance that you need to use an indefinite article with such a symbol at all, my own personal preference would be to simply use the simplest form of the article, ***a***. But there is no logical reason that ***an*** should not be equally correct.

Comment: +1 In this particular case replacing _a/an_ with _the_ might resolve some issues, leaving the reader to decide whether to say 'the' or 'thee'.

Comment: +1, although I wonder how many people _really_ stumble at _a #_ because they read it _octothorpe_... I think they had it coming for using that word :P Then again... _a SQL-statement_ or _an SQL-statement_?

Comment: @oerkelens: When two pronunciations are possible, the author chooses the article that matches their pronunciation, and readers who use the other pronunciation get annoyed, but such is life. I get annoyed when people write "an historical".

Comment: @oerkelens: Would be your decision. I'd have to change the way I read it (an ess-queue-ell statement or a sequel statement) and I think I would do that automatically.

Comment: I don't intend to be rude, but who really uses the word "octothorpe"?! From what I've heard, US generally goes with "hash" while Europe (UK especially) goes with "pound". That might be a little off, but still, I rarely (if ever) heard of "octothorpe" :)

Comment: It's rare to use articles at all with Hanzi characters. They're words, after all. It'd be “How do you write “字”?”, like “How do you spell “character”?”. The occasion on which they may get an article is if one sees the character written somewhere and wants to say “I saw an\? ‘字’.”.

Comment: @BogdanAlexandru I'd be surprised if many people in the UK used “pound”, since we already have the ‘£’ symbol. If anything, it'd be the other way round. Note that ‘#’ appears on US keyboards where ‘£’ is on UK keyboards.

Comment: @BogdanAlexandru : octothorpe was the the first thing I thought of as a problem when I read the question ... and based on this answer, I wasn't the only one.  If you don't like that example, `*` can be 'asterisk' or 'star' (eg, '*69' on the phone), so has the same issue.

Comment: @DavidRicherby As an American, I'd know what key you were referring to if you said "hash", but "pound" is still most common by a wide margin. For example, many automated phone services that request you to input information (such as an account number, etc.) will end with the instruction "... followed by the pound key".  Very rarely, they'll compromise by stating both. ("pound or hash key")

Comment: @BogdanAlexandru It's the other way around. People in the UK refer to the # key on a telephone as "hash" and, as James Wood says, never "pound" because that is the currency, £. I've only ever heard of Americans calling # "pound".

Comment: @DavidRicherby My mistake then, I know I've heard about this US/UK distinction somewhere some time ago and I must have reversed them :)

Comment: @JamesWood Just saw your comment regarding CJK characters now. I’d say an article before a CJK character is common enough in the same circumstance as an article before any random word in English: when using it as a word-as-word. For example, if you see “We went to to the beach today”, you could say, “There’s a ‘to’ that shouldn’t be there”; and if you see “今天下午我们要要去海滩”, you could say, “There’s a ‘要’ there that’s been doubled”. Not necessarily very common, but it can easily happen. (This goes for both _@_ and _#_, too, of course.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet you're correct. I hadn't thought of that one. One thing to note: this only need apply to hanzi, since kana and hangeul characters & jamo have unique phonetic names. With hanzi, I guess one has to take the phonetic value (and dialect) from context.

Comment: And in math, ≡ can be called called an "equivalence" or a "congruence" sign.

Comment: @PeterShor I’ll take your word for it! I only know it as [_qián_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagua) in quite a different context. :-)

Comment: When in doubt, consider providing the reader with _your_ version of the pronunciation: _The name of the decorator should be prepended with an "at" (@) symbol. If you use a hash (#) instead, ..._