# Where did "nightingale" get its second N from?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, phonology

I noticed while searching the etymology of the word **nightingale** that it did not have the second **N**. The sources I checked only say **intrusive N** but don't explain it.

[Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nightingale):

> From Middle English *nyghtyngale*, *nightingale*, *niȝtingale*, **alteration (with intrusive n) of *nyghtgale***, *nightegale*, from Old English *nihtegala*, *nihtegale*

[Etymology Dictionary:](https://www.etymonline.com/word/nightingale)

> Middle English ***nighte-gale***, from Old English ***næctigalæ***, in late Old English ***nihtegale***, a compound formed in Proto-Germanic (compare Dutch *nachtegaal*, German *Nachtigall*) from **nakht-* "night" (see night) + **galon* "to sing," related to Old English *giellan* "to yell" (from PIE root ***ghel-** (1) "to call").

As you can see, in Old English and Middle English, it did not have the second **N** so the present day **N** is not original.

Etymology Dictionary also says "With parasitic -n- that began to appear mid-13c." but doesn't explain the reason English people put it in "Nightegale".

Can anyone explain the reason?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The epenthetic *n* ([ŋ]) has been inserted for articulatory reasons. It eases the passage between the preceding unstressed vowel and the following consonant.

### Epenthesis

Epenthesis is the pronunciation of an unhistorical sound within a word. Consonants and vowels are usually inserted into words for the sake of ease. Epenthesis happens for a variety of reasons, some of them are:

- to prevent adjacent vowels in a [hiatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiatus_(linguistics)), for instance, *idea of* is sometimes pronounced [idearof](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/32630/365490), *law and order* is pronounced *law**r**and order* (with an epenthetic *r*), in most non-rhotic accents to avoid a hiatus
- another reason is to simplify consonant clusters, for instance, most Indian English speakers pronounce 'school' ***i**school*
- [transition between a nasal and a fricative](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/564971/365490) e.g. PRINCE-PRINTS merger

Some examples of epenthetic stops are:

- *length* is almost always pronounced *leng**k**th*, with an epenthetic *k* between the nasal [ŋ] and the oral fricative [θ] ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/length) gives a parenthetical k in its transcription)
- [*warmth*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/warmth) and [*hamster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hamster) are often pronounced *warm**p**th* and *ham**p**ster*, respectively (with an epenthetic p)
- *thun**d**er* used to be *þunor*, the d is epenthetic.
- the *n* in *passe**n**ger, messe**n**ger, nighti**n**gale*

Epenthetic stops also occur at the end, for instance, [the p in *nope*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/535950/365490). 'Vowel epenthesis' also exists, for example, *film* is pronounced 'fil[**ə**]m' in most dialects.

### Epenthetic nasal in 'nightingale'

According to [*Garner's Modern English Usage*](https://books.google.com/books?id=mSjnCwAAQBAJ) (p1003), the *n* in *nightingale, passenger, messenger* is epenthetic, though Garner doesn't explain the reason.

Donka Minkova in her [*A Historical Phonology of English*](https://books.google.com/books/about/A_Historical_Phonology_of_English.html?id=uGs3BQAAQBAJ) also says that in late Middle English, there was a development of the *epenthesis of /-n/ or [-ŋ] in the coda of unstressed syllables before the voiced velar stop /-g/ or the affricate /-d͡ʒ/* mostly in loanwords: *harb**ing**er, mess**eng**er, night**ing**ale*. She further says that “Dobson (1968: §438) calls the nasal 'a species of consonantal glide', easing the passage between the preceding unstressed vowel and the following consonant”.

Here's the relevant bit from Dobson:

> > 'INTRUSIVE' [n] and [ŋ]
> > §438.The 'intrusive' [n] in messenger, papenjay, &c. and [ŋ] in nightingale and paringale 'equal' (<paregal) is a species of consonantal glide easing the passage between the preceding vowel and the following [ʤ] or [g], and is found chiefly in adopted words; it is perhaps, as has been suggested, associated with a desire to make weightier the middle syllable so as to avoid syncope . . . . It appears to develop at various dates from the thirteenth century (nightingale) onwards. In words in which it is an established feature of StE, e.g. *nightingale* and *messenger*, it is regularly shown by the ortheopists. Salesbury has *potanger* 'potager' and *Portingal* (but the latter must represent an OE variant; see OED, s.v.); Coles says *pottinger* is pronounced *porringer*. ...
>
> [Dobson, E. J. English Pronunciation 1500--1700. 2nd ed. Vol. 2. Oxford: OUP, 1968.]

According to Dobson, the reason for the insertion of the nasal is to avoid syncope. Unstressed and coda-less syllables are rather prone to [syncope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syncope_(phonology)). *Syncope* is the loss of segments from the interior of a word, especially unstressed vowel and sometimes syllables. For example, the unstressed, coda-less syllables in words like *fam.ly, cam.ra, happ.ning, av.rage* have been syncopated for many speakers. So the *n* in *nightingale* acts as a coda of the unstressed syllable and prevents syncope.

[*The Cambridge Handbook of English Historical Linguistics*](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Cambridge_Handbook_of_English_Histor.html?id=NrkaDAAAQBAJ) by Merja Kytö and Päivi Pahta says that this epenthetic n optimises the structure of the syllable by increasing the consonantal nature of the syllable:

> **One possible reason for this epenthesis is that the addition of a stop increases the consonantal nature of the syllable coda, thus optimizing the structure of the syllable** (Blevins 1995). Consonant epenthesis can also occur wordinternally but with the same apparent motivation, compare English *thunder*–with /-nd-/ – and German *Donner*. *A further instance of this type of epenthesis is the insertion of a nasal in an unstressed syllable before /ɡ/, i.e. /ˌV.ɡV/→ /ˌVŋ.ɡV/* as in ME *nightigale* → *nightingale*; ME *messager* → *messenger*(Jespersen 1909: 35ff., Dobson 1968: 1004).

In her *Evolutionary Phonology*, Juliette Blevins says that epenthesis is often considered to have an optimising effect on the syllable structure.

If I understand it correctly, this means that English syllables don't often end in short vowels like /ʌ ɪ æ ɒ/ etc., so the epenthetic nasal [ŋ] serves as the coda of the short vowel /ɪ/. According to another phonological rule [**Maximal Onset Principle**](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/558949/365490), intervocalic consonants are syllabified as the onset of the following syllable as long as the [phonotactic constraints](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/548361/365490) of the language allow it. If 'nightingale' were without the nasal [ŋ], it would've been syllabified as */naɪ.tɪg.eɪl/, which would be awkward-to-pronounce. The nasal [ŋ] therefore acts as the coda of the second syllable, making the following syllable easy-to-pronounce. Also as far as I know, some languages disfavour word-medial onset-less syllables for some reasons. Now when [ŋ] becomes the coda of the second syllable, then the [g] becomes the onset of the next syllable:

- /naɪ.tɪŋ.geɪl/

---

Read the following sources for more discussion on the topic:

- [Phonological Change in English - Raymond Hickey p10](https://www.uni-due.de/%7Elan300/CHEHL_Hickey_Phonological_Change_in_English.pdf)
- [The intrusive nasal in 'nightingale'](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/abs/10.1086/386591)
- A Modern English Grammar on Historical Principles by Otto Jesperson
- [Selected Writings of Otto Jespersen p342](https://www.routledge.com/Selected-Writings-of-Otto-Jespersen-Routledge-Revivals/Jespersen/p/book/9780415573023)
- [Intrusive Nasals in English - JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2916901?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents)

Comment: Spectacular answer. Some people said "because English" but I knew that there would be an excellent answer (like yours).

Comment: Are there other examples of introducing a nasal before a velar like those three? I feel like three instances is not enough of a pattern.

Comment: @Mitch: Maybe. I didn't find any other examples

Comment: There are *harbinger, messenger, passenger* and *scavenger*, but the nasal is followed by the affricate [dʒ], not a velar.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul The alveolar-palatal affricate pattern in messenger/passenger from OF borrowings seems sufficiently distinct from the velar in 'nightingale'. Also, the 'n' insertion, is in the other direction from the classic -loss- of a nasal (before a fricative, eg [ProGer *muntha- -> MSE mouth](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=mouth). So it is interesting to see a pattern that sort of flips after a while.

Comment: @Mitch: I checked several Phonology/Historical Linguistics books, but didn't find a single instance of this occurrence. (I took so much time in writing this answer even the question was closed but I [posted my answer anyway](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316139/711871).)

Comment: I feel like epenthetic needs an epenthesis somewhere. But not epenthesis, oddly enough. I think it's the stress alternation

Answer (score -3):

English is the result of a collision between a dozen different languages, further convoluted by a mix of cultures. Asking why a particular pronunciation of a particular word dominated is often a fool's errand.

And in the particular case of "nightingale" the general reason for the N being inserted is probably that it made the word easier to pronounce.  English words tend to morph in favor of easier pronunciation.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. What's your take on Decapitated Soul's answer? Would you still say "because English"? And why is this answer downvoted so much (I haven't downvoted btw)? I guess it's the result of your comment "because English".

Comment: @Sphinx - Basically I'm saying the same thing as Decapitated Soul, only without technical jargon and the (moderately boring) quotations.  I suppose you could say he explains it better, but nothing he said contradicts what I said.  And "because English" is just saying "This is how English works.  Live with it!"  I don't know why several folks here got Pist over this.