# What is the trend in pronouncing the word "strength"?

Tags: dialects, phonology, fast-speech-rules, palatalization, consonant-clusters

Over the years, I have heard 3 different ways to pronounce the word **strength**:

1. *stre(ng)kth* /stɹɛŋkθ/
2. *strenth* /st̠͡ɹ̠ɛn̪θ/
3. *shtrength* /ʃtɹɛŋθ/

I definitely pronounce it with option 3 (*shtrength* /ʃtɹɛŋθ/), starting the word with an /ʃ/ ("sh").

For me, option 2 (*strenth* /st̠͡ɹ̠ɛn̪θ/) sounds too simplified as there is not even an ŋ, although I have heard others say it that way.

I am curious about option 1: /stɹɛŋkθ/.  I am having trouble hearing (and saying) the very soft k that is being inserted after the /ŋ/ and before the /θ/.  Do people still pronounce the word this way, or is it more often pronounced as option 2 or 3?

[image]

Comment: In my experience, the pronunciation with the [epenthetic](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/564971/365490) *k* is more common among native anglophones.

Comment: I use 1.  I dislike 2 and 3.   2 because there’s a g in it. 3 because where do you get the ‘sh’?

Comment: First figure out how to say *rain*, then prefix that with *t* to make *train*, leaving *rain* intact. Then prefix that with *s* to make *strain*, leaving *train* intact. Finally add *θ* to the end of *strain* to make *strength* without changing any sound you used in *strain*.  Now you're done! See [this related answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/146803) which shows *trade* as [t͡ʂɻʷeɪd], and [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/111931) and [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/10311). Compare with *strengths* and *strengthens*. These are all natural phonologic processes.

Comment: @Jim I was also surprised to realize that I say "sh" to start the word!  Apparently it's a thing:. 
 Like the author here, I say "stripe, street, straight, struck, and straddled": https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-s-backing-causes-people-to-pronounce-street-as-schtreet

Comment: @tchrist Interesting that you have an alternate pronunciation using a Long A vowel...  I prefer that greatly to option 2.  But it's harder to say with rapid speech, I think.  And feels a little hard to use that approach when pronouncing the related *length*.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Thank you for introducing me to the word *epenthetic*!  How do you define native Anglophone?

Comment: @kanamekun: Someone who grew up speaking English

Comment: The reason you get effectively get a "long" vowel in *strength* and *length* is because of the palatal nasal ŋ there. That naturally closes off the open ɛ into a close e via assimilation. That doesn’t happen with *tenth* because you can keep it open there. I'll try to write a proper answer if I find time.

Comment: shtrength is Brooklynese. Or NY/NJ, too. strenth is mostly southern or western. Most upper east coasters use 1). Those that say shtrength also will say: shtrong.

Comment: I think the only time I'd say "shtrength" was if I was trying to do a Sean Connery impression.

Comment: I say *strenkth* and hear it that way most frequently here (Chicago) among native speakers.  My wife says it as *strenth* .  Although she's also a native here, I believe she learned it from her mother's western PA accent.  I don't think I have ever heard *shtrength*.  If @Lambie is right that it's NY/NJ, I wonder if it's origin is German/Yiddish?

Comment: @Theodore No, [it is not Yiddish](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/10311/2085). It's a natural phonological effect. These happen everywhere, doncha know.

Comment: @tchrist I guess I should have said "proximate origin" or something like that: I know palatalization *just happens*, but I wondered whether this particular kind it's more likely to happen in an English dialect where there is a substantial Yiddish substratum.

Comment: The vowel I use in _strength_ is more like the one I use in _ink_ than the one I use in _train_. I have the pen/pin merger.

Answer (score 1):

My apologies.  I read the question too quickly, and did not notice the question was about the pronunciation of the "k".  My previous answer was in regards to the "sh" sound in your third example.  **Sh**trength is incorrect pronunciation.  Only  "sh" in a first syllable makes the "sh" sound in English.  In a second syllable, "ci", "ti", and "si" can also make the "sh" sound.  The "str" in **str**ength should be pronounced like the "str" in **str**eet.

Regarding the pronunciation of stre**ngth**...such an interesting question.  The correct pronunciation is your third example (minus the "sh"), as the "ng" in strength should be pronounced like the "ng" in hu**ng**, which is formed by placing the tongue back in the throat.  Then followed by the "th" as in "**th**ree", which is formed by placing the tongue between the teeth.  Perhaps it is all this tongue moving..lol..or two soft phonograms next to each other that causes a US speaker to add a hard "k" to make the pronunciation easier.  It is incorrect pronunciation, but I use it myself.  So minus the "sh", #3 is how strength SHOULD be pronounced.  #1 is how it is USUALLY pronounced (as it is easier on the lazy tongue). Occasionally I hear #2 - it may be a British pronunciation, and that is what it sounds like to the American ear.

Comment: Frankly, as a new contributor, I did not think you deserved such a rude first response. People around here get pretty cranky. :)

Comment: Thank you for your kind words.  I am unfamiliar with this site, and only posted because I am trying to learn Spanish and have been very grateful for the individuals answering my questions on the "Spanish Stack Exchange".  I thought I could "repay the favor" by answering a few questions on the "English Stack Exchange".  But is this a site only for language teachers or linguistic experts or something?  Perhaps I should not post here.  I was thinking it was just people enjoying learning a new language.  My input is simply as a native speaker trying to help, not a linguistic expert.  Thanks

Comment: Chris, try the English Language Learner's site. :)

Answer (score 0):

Asking about “strength” is a big question because you’re really asking about two fairly distinct pronounciation issues: the pronunciation of “ength” and the pronunciation of “str”. People mostly pronounced strength in a way that rhymes with *length* and alliterates with *string* or *stream.*

Dealing with “str” first, the usual pronunciation is with /s/ as in “soon”, but some speakers replace the s sound with a sound more like a sh sound when it comes before -tr- (or even sometimes in other consonant clusters, but str- is the most common context). There is no contrast between s and sh in this context in regular English words. See the citations here for more info: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/30111/about-s-being-replaced-by-the-voiceless-postalveolar-fricative-in-the-us/30133#30133

With “ength”, a pronunciation as “enth” is somewhat common; it’s also possible to hear “ingth”, “ayngth”, or “inth”. The insertion of a [k] or [t] sound before the -th is a type of epenthesis.

Comment: Well, the point is that [the normal pronunciation "tr" is as an affricate and a resonant](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/146803), not a stop and a resonant, which is why small children first learning to spell naturally spell words *chree, chrade, chrain, chruck, chrungk* and all the rest. There's really nothing to see here with *str* because this is just [simplification of the cluster via regressive assimilation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146795/what-is-the-ipa-for-trade?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment302641_146795) to the next sound following the sibililant in the cluster.