# An or a in given sentence scenario

Tags: grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I use “a” vs “an”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/when-should-i-use-a-vs-an)

Sorry I couldn't think of a better title, but I don't know how to explain my problem using terminology.

I have this sentence:

"Aside from that I'm **an** Irish Setter loving, Frank Turner junkie."

I understand you should use the word "an" over "a" when the following word begins with a vowel. In this case, it does. However, the sentence is meant to flow through to the word "junkie" – if that makes sense. And if you read it like this, it doesn't make sense to use "an":

"I'm an … Frank Turner junkie."

Should I be using "a" or "an" in this sentence?

Comment: We have four dozen questions on the subject and even a [dedicated blog post](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/articles-a-vs-an/). The answer is always the same. And you even spell it out yourself in your question. "I understand you should use the word *an* over *a* when the following word begins with a vowel." If you understand that, you understand the subject in its entirety. That is all there is to it. No *however*. No *but*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter what the article is meant to "flow through," it should just properly match whatever it precedes. In this case:

> An Irish

Comment: yup, a/an is just phonological.  There's no semantics.