# "as such that" vs. "such that"

Tags: word-usage, tenses

I would like to see if the following sentence is correct:

(context: the tool performs an analysis during which alarms may be raised)

> *1.* we had set up the tool such that a raised alarm stops the whole analysis.

Someone proposed

> *2.* we had set up the tool as such that a raised alarm stops the whole analysis.
>   *3.* we had set up the tool such that a raised alarm would stop the whole analysis.
>   *4.* we had set up the tool as such that a raised alarm would stop the whole analysis.

Comment: Yes 1) works. But why had, why not have?

Comment: [When to use *a* vs *an*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/when-should-i-use-a-vs-an)

Comment: Also, you might be interested in our sister site: [ell.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(2) and (4) are certainly wrong.

I felt uncomfortable with the use of 'such that ...' (which is normally adjectival) to stand in for the standard adverbial 'in such a way that ...' in the other sentences. I was not surprised by this comment from the [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/such):

> Usage Note: The adjective *such* is often followed by *that* when *such* is
>   used to mean "of a degree or quality indicated," as in the sentence
>   *The demand of Feinberg's specialized services is such that he commands
>   around $200,000 a month when he gets involved in a case.* This example
>   is acceptable to 87 percent of the Usage Panel. · The Panel does not,
>   however, find the phrase *such that* to be an acceptable replacement for
>   *so that* or *in such a way that*. A mere 12 percent approve of this usage
>   in the sentence *The products are packaged [/ We package the products] such that users can pick the
>   components they need and add capabilities over time*.

so I'd opt for:

> We have set up the tool in such a way that a raised alarm will stop
>   the whole analysis.