# How can I ask about a confirmation?

Tags: phrases, paraphrasing

Two heroes are available.

> Hero #1: Please, send me an URL to that site.
>     Here #2: Go to www.bla.bla. Is it true that you look for?

Is the phrase "Is it true that you look for" correct?

How else could I say this?

Comment: 'Look for' requires an object, which your sentence lacks.

Comment: As an aside, you [likely mean "a URL"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/when-should-i-use-a-vs-an), unless you pronounce "URL" as "earl", which only very few people ever do.

Comment: I think you meant something like "Is it the site you were looking for?"

Comment: @RegDwigнt People really do pronounce it that way.  (Less often than they used to, though…?)  Yahoo!'s cafeteria is still called *URL's Cafe*.

Comment: I think I don't know English =(

Comment: Can you perhaps tell us in Russian what it is you are trying to say? While you're at it, what's the deal with "heroes"? Very confusing.

Comment: Ест два участника:
Первый: Пожалуйста, пришли мне ссылку того сайта
Второй: Иди сюда www.bla.bla. Это то, что ты искал?

Comment: Not sure, then, where you got *heroes* from, or *true*. "There are two participants. A: Please, send me a link to that site. B: head to www.bla.bla. Is that what you've been looking for?" Or "Is this what you're looking for", or "is this the site you mean", or "is that what you're after", or "does it help", or any number of other rewordings.

Comment: In the future, please take such questions to our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage), or to our dedicated [sister site for learners of the language](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). Thank you.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanov, just saw your comment on not knowing English.  It isn't so bad to not know English.  We can start anytime learn fast enough!  It is an accommodating language!  Please see if my answer below makes sense to you.  Feel free to comment on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PART 1: The Right Site**

There are many ways of saying it.  Some examples are:

```
Is that what you are looking for?
Is it the one you are looing for?
Is that the site you are looking for?
Is that the right site?
Does it match what you were expecting?
```

`True` cannot always be substituted for `correct` or `right`.  I guess that is where your confusion stems from.

For instance, you **can** substitute `correct` or `right` for `true` in the following sentence:

> This religion is the true way to salvation.

But you **cannot** substitute true for right (or correct) in the following one:

> This road is the right way to Houston.

Hope this helps.

**PART 2: A URL**

As RegDwight has mentioned above, `an` should be used for vowel sounds and not literally for vowel letters.  For instance, the following are **correct**:

> an honest man, an hour, an umbrella, an apple, an invention, an
>   elephant

But the following are **incorrect**:

> an user, an united front, an U.N.O. member

So, it should be `a URL` instead of `an URL`, if you are pronouncing it as *you-are-el*. Also, since Hero #1 says "that site" and hence indicates a specific site, `**the URL**` will be more apt in your case unless you expect the site to have more than one URL (which is also entirely possible).

Feel free to ask if any of is unclear.

Comment: Glad to be of help, @AlexanderIvanov.  

By the way, your comment should use "has" instead of "have", as you are referring to a single post.  The correct way to say this would be, "Your post HAS enlightened me."

Happy learning!

Answer (score 1):

In context, the following two possibilities make sense:

1. Are you there yet? 
   (*I have given you a URL and I'd like to know if you have reached the webpage yet.*)
2. Is this the page you were looking for?
    (*I have given you a URL and I would like confirmation that the result is indeed the result you expected.*)