# When did the a/an distinction happen?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, indefinite-articles

Why do we have two versions of the indefinite article? When did this happen? Are there any texts where only one is used?

Comment: This is a purely sandhi effect.  It is automatic and implicit in correct speech.  Your mouth just does it, exactly the same as it chooses alternate ways to say the definite article *the* under different phonetic environments — which are the same ones as determine how to pronounce *a* and *an*.

Comment: It takes more effort to use one or the other all the time than it does to use them in the usual fashion.  People are inherently lazy.

Comment: For the same reason we have two versions of the **definite** article. Sandhi, as @tchrist points out, following precisely the same rule, in precisely the same environments.

Comment: In Old English, there was no indefinite article. In Middle English, the indefinite article was *an* (descended from the Old English word for *one*, which was *an*). By Shakespeare's time, the 'n' was being dropped before consonants.

Comment: Related: [Was “an unicorn” ever correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198788)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following extract may help understand the origin and evolution of *a* and *an*  ( see also *the juncture loss* below).

> **[Indefinite article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_articles#Indefinite_article)**:
>
> - The indefinite article of English takes the two forms *a* and *an*. ***Semantically they can be regarded as meaning "one",*** usually without emphasis. They can be used only with singular countable nouns; for the possible use of *some* (or *any*) as an equivalent with plural and uncountable nouns.
> - **Distinction between *a* and *an*:**
> - The form ***an*** is used before words starting with a vowel sound, regardless of whether the word begins with a vowel letter. This avoids the glottal stop (momentary silent pause) that would otherwise be required between *a* and a following vowel sound. Where the next word begins with a consonant sound, **a is used**. Examples: *a box*; *an apple*; *an SSO* (pronounced "es-es-oh"); *a HEPA filter* (HEPA is pronounced as a word rather than as letters); *an hour* (the h is silent); a one-armed bandit (pronounced "won..."); *an heir* (pronounced "air"); a unicorn (pronounced "yoo-"); *an herb* in American English (where the h is silent), but *a herb* in British English.

**Pronunciation**

> - Both a and an are usually pronounced with a *schwa*: /ə/, /ən/. However, when stressed (which is rare in ordinary speech), they are normally pronounced respectively as /eɪ/ (to rhyme with *day*) and /æn/ (to rhyme with *pan*). See Weak and strong forms in English.

**Etymology**

> - *An* is the older form (related to one, cognate to German ein; etc.). *An* was originally an unstressed form of the number *ān* 'one'.

**Juncture loss**:

> - **In a process called *juncture loss*, the *n* has wandered back and forth between the indefinite article and words beginning with vowels over the history of the language, where for example what was once *a nuncle* is now *an* uncle.**
> - The *Oxford English Dictionary* gives such examples as “smot hym on the hede with a nege tool” from 1448 for “smote him on the head with an edge tool”, as well as “a nox“ for *an ox* and “a napple“ for *an apple*. Sometimes the change has been permanent. For example, *a newt* was once “an ewt“ (earlier *euft* and *eft*), a nickname was once “an eke-name”, where *eke* means "extra" (as in *eke out* meaning "add to"), and in the other direction, “a napron” (meaning *a little tablecloth*, related to the word *napkin*) became *an apron*, and “a naddre” became *an adder*. The initial *n* in *orange* was also dropped through juncture loss, but this happened before the word was borrowed into English.

(English articles: Wikipedia)

Comment: +1, particularly for 'nickname' in the 'Juncture loss' section. Would you mind editing in the link to the wikipedia article?

Comment: @Lawrence done, I had forgotten about this answer until I had to do some personal research about silent H's in English. The Wikipedia article is very useful and interesting. Thank you Josh for finding it!