# Why the "oo" in "noon" is pronounced sounding like "you" while the word "moon" isn't?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, phonetics, yod-dropping

I was taught to pronounce the *oo* in either *afternoon* or *noon* as /u:/ ~~the oo in nook~~ until I found some native speakers pronounce the *noon* sounding like *new-n* ([videos](https://youglish.com/pronounce/Good%20Afternoon/english/us?)). But the AmE IPA in the [dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/afternoon) labels it as /nu:n/, instead of what I thought it as /nju:n/ if it's pronounced *new-n*. To my surprise, the IPA of *new* is /nu:/ rather than /nju:/. If /u:/ is equivalent to /ju:/, so why the word *moon*, whose IPA is /mu:n/, is not pronounced as mew-n?

Comment: I suspect there is a combination rule applied when /n/ meets /ju:/ and contracts as /mu:/.

Comment: I pronounce _moon_ and _noon_ with the same vowel.

Comment: I think you're talking about [the *diphthong* that distinguishes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198788/was-an-unicorn-ever-correct#comment420120_198788) ***beaut*** (short for "beautiful") from ***boot***. But neither ***noon*** nor ***moon*** are enunciated using the diphthong corresponding to ***you, ewe,*** the letter *'**u**'*.

Comment: In BrE the pronunciation of 'oo' is regional, but some words vary, and others don't.

Comment: For /nu:/ or /nju:/, check whether that source claims to be US or UK pronunciation.

Comment: I've been all over the Anglosphere, and I've never, _ever_ heard of anyone pronouncing 'moon' like 'new-n'. I want to know where this was heard by @GuoyangQin.

Comment: @Michael-Harvey, I didn't mean I heard people pronounced *mewn*. I just use this word as a contrast to the word noon, and emphasize why both of them **share the vowel /u:/** in their AmE IPAs, but only *noon* can pronounce like nju:n, the *moon* cannot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In much of the U.S., /u:/ and /ju:/ have *merged* after /t/, /d/, and /n/.

That means if you pronounce *noon* as /nju:n/, people will still understand you, and probably won't even notice you're pronouncing it differently than they do. I don't know if I've heard people use /ju:/ after /n/, but I've definitely heard it after /d/ and /t/. This is generally called yod-dropping, which would imply that the /j/ is dropped, but it might be more useful to think of it as a merger, as there are some people who pronounce both *due* and *do* (when it's stressed( as /dju:/.

On the other hand, these two phonemes have only merged after some consonants, and not after others like /m/, /p/, /b/, /f/, /k/, and /h/; if you pronounce *moon* as /mju:n/, you're much less likely to be understood; in fact the two words *moot* /mu:t/ and *mute* /mju:t/ are distinguished by the /j/, and if you say “it's a mute issue,” it's not clear you'll be understood.

Finally, the 'oo' is *nook* is a different phoneme than is in either *mute* or *moot*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. *yod-dropping* is a helpful explanation and interesting phenomenon. Just wondering why adding /j/ sound after some consonants like /n/, /d/, /t/ doesn't feel quite different. Namely, newn and noon, due and do, tune and toon sounds closer (heard the audio multiple times I began to be unsure of which sound they had pronounced), or more unnoticeable as you suggested, than say mewn and moon, beaut and boot, mute and moot.

Comment: Have /u:/ and /ju:/ merged into /u/ or something else?

Comment: @Richard: Most people pronounce the merged vowel /u/, but some people pronounce it /ju/.  And I think these people are the ones the OP's hearing and is puzzled by. For merged phonemes, sometimes both pronunciations are valid.

Answer (score 4):

> I was taught to pronounce the oo in either afternoon or noon as the oo in nook

That was poor teaching - it is wrong.

Standard pronunciation:

**noon**, n.Brit. /nuːn/; U.S. /nun/;

**moon**, n.Brit. /muːn/; U.S. /mun/

**nook**, n. Brit. /nʊk/, U.S. /nʊk/ (some dialects pronounce as /nuːk/ particularly parts of Scotland - but this is non-standard.)

> until I found native speakers pronounce the noon sounding like new-n.

[Newn] is non-standard or dialect - **you need to say where these "native speakers" are from.**

The "y" sound ([j]) found in "new" - nyew - is know as **the intrusive y** and is [a feature of English](https://www.speakmoreclearly.com/english-pronunciation-tips/english-accent-sound-natural-how-to-use-the-intrusive-y-audio-training/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my OALD app, AmE IPAs of (after)noon and moon are labeled as /nu:n/ and /mu:n/, where the audio of the pronunciation of /nu:n/ sounds like new-n (www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/afternoon). Noon sounds like new-n too in M-W (www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/afternoon). I also check videos with "good afternoon" (youglish.com/pronounce/Good%20Afternoon/english/us?), some of them pronounced like new-n.

Comment: @GuoyangQin Have a look at Word Reference Forums for the entry in their dictionary for "noon", "moon", "nook" and "new". (https://www.wordreference.com/definition/noon) You will find all of the words pronounced in various versions of English. You will not find "new-n"

Comment: @Greybeard: that's only because the dictionaries are reporting the "standard pronunciation", which is not necessarily how all people actually pronounce things. Some Americans say *newn* and not *noon*.

Comment: Possibly what's confusing is that some (many?) Americans pronounce "new" not as /njuː/ but as /nu/, hence when we say that "noon" sounds like "new" + n, we mean it sounds like the American /nu/ + /n/, not like the British /nju:/ + /n/.

Comment: @shoover - I reckon that's it.