# Which is the correct article here?

Tags: articles

## 1

An n-dimensional generalisation

OR

## 2

A n-dimensional generalisation.

I would like to say the first is correct but my friend insists the second.
**Which is the correct way?**

Comment: You are correct. You can point you friend to this question, which yours is a duplicate of [When should I use "a" vs "an"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/152)

Comment: So far as I can see this visually misleading case is not explicitly covered in Alan's reference. We are sometimes taught to determine "a" versus "an" by considering whether the following word starts with a vowel or consonant, and seeing the consonant "n" think "a". The determinant is, as Alan's reference says, the pronunciation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determined by pronunciation: n is pronounced "en" and therefore starts with a vowel so use **an**.

```
A two-dimensional generalisation.
An n-dimensional generalisation
```

and, because one is pronounced won

```
A one-dimensional generalisation
```