# Why is "union" an exception to the "a/an" rule?

Tags: grammaticality

Usually when a word starts with a vowel, we will use "an" before it. But for *union*, it is "a union" not "an union." It is not explained in the previously mentioned [a vs an](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/when-should-i-use-a-vs-an) why *union* is an exception. It explains how to know exceptions for h like hotels.

Also are there any exceptions for the opposite side, where there should be an "a" but is an "an" instead? (Unfortunately I have no example of a case like this.)

Comment: "An institution of higher learning"... Remember, it's not words that begin with a vowel, it's a **vowel sound**. "union" begins with a "yoo" sound, which is a consonant sound, like Ukulele.

Comment: But they did not explain the exception and I still don't understand the exceptions. :(

Comment: Perhaps if you rephrase your question to be specific to the "union" question and not to the broader "a vs an" situation.

Comment: @user1470901 It's *not* an exception. The *pronunciation* governs whether *a* or *an* is used, not the spelling, as three people have now explained. Thus, *a one-piece suit*, *an FBI badge*, *a xylophone*, *an X-ray*, *a euro account* — and it's *an herb garden* for Americans even if it's *a herb garden* for most Britons.

Comment: All other words, such as "cake", "pie", and **"user"** (which begins with a y sound), are preceded by "a". — the above is written in the linked question. "Union" is exactly parallel to "user." It is not an exception.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *a/an-rule* is **based on pronunciation**, not on spelling. Though the word *union* is spelt beginning with a vowel, the *u* is pronounced *"you"*:

> /ˈjuː.ni.ən/

So, this is why it is accompanied by *a* rather than *an* and this is also the case for many other words starting with a vowel, have a look at these:

> - a user
> - a European

but:

> - an ultimatum
> - an orange

Note that there are words which start with an *h* and when that *h* is not pronounced, these words also go with *an*:

> an honor

However, if this *h* is pronounced, then the article used is *a*:

> - a hill
> - a heathen

Here's a short but clear article that explains the usage of *a/an*: [Articles: A versus An](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/591/01/)

Comment: @DogLover Please don’t answer duplicates. No one will ever find them. And they should be closed anyway.

Comment: @tchrist I did not answer this question; I commented on an answer.

Comment: Updated link [Articles: A versus An](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/articles_a_versus_an.html)