# Pronunciation of ‘an hundred’

Tags: grammar, pronunciation, archaicisms

I just saw a number of comments complaining about the first n in the phrase ‘an Herculean task’, claiming it implied a mute h. But is that true? My impression has been that earlier all words on h + vowel got an an, regardless of whether or not the h was mute. Was ‘an hundred’ pronounced ‘an undred’?

PS. Let me be clearer that I am not asking about standard contemporary usage. I never doubted that ‘an Herculean task’ had an archaïc ring to it. But the fact that something is archaïc does not make it wrong.

Comment: This may be a British versus American thing. In the US it's supposed to be "a hundred" and "an hundred" sounds bizarre, but we say "an honor."

Comment: Agree with @MattSamuel. Some h's which are silent in BrE are voiced in AmE. I would never say "an Herculean task" or "an hundred", but would say, "an herb/hour/honor/etc. You need to consult an appropriate dictionary to learn which is which.

Comment: @medica actually the "h" isn't silent at all in those words in British English either I believe, they just have a different rule for the article.

Comment: @MattSamuel - Thanks! That makes it rather complicated. An Herculean?

Comment: @medica I believe the rule is just as the OP says, though my only knowledge of it is second hand from my wife who's from Guyana.

Comment: @Lawrence As an aside, already heard it pronounced as if spelled "hunderd."

Comment: I don't think modern British English differs much from American English on this matter. What people may be getting confused with is 17th century English, such as is Shakespeare or the KJV - *an hundredfold*.

Comment: @medica I'd only differ with 'a herb' from your five examples. OP has clarified that he is asking about earlier usages though, now.

Answer (score 2):

*"An Herculean task"* is acceptable because *"Herculean"* can be accented on the second syllable, and there are a number of speakers that drop the /h/ and use *"an"* for words that begin with an /h/ and are not stressed on the first syllable. (I live in New England, and there are quite a few people who do that here. I believe it's a lot less common in other regions of the US.)

I have no idea why *"an hundred"* was used, or how it should be pronounced. 
It used to be quite common, but it's fallen completely out of use today. However, in the last two or three centuries, it certainly has not been true that all words starting with /h/ got *"an"*; it has been *"a horse"* for the last three hundred years, while *an hundred* was quite common in 1800. ([See Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+hundred%2Ca+hundred%2Can+horse%2Ca+horse&year_start=1650&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=6&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Can%20hundred%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hundred%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20horse%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20horse%3B%2Cc0) and consider Shakespeare's *"my kingdom for a horse"*.)

Because there are several searchable versions of Shakespeare's works online, we can look at the words Shakespeare used *"an"* with. 
He always used *an* with

> Hebrew, heir, heretic, honest, honour, hour, humble, hypocrite.

I believe we can conclude that he pronounced these without an "h" (even though there is only one instance of *an Hebrew* and *an hypocrite*).

He used *"an"* once each with

> happy, hand, hasty, heroical, household,

and for all of these, there were several usages with *"a"* (at least if you count other forms, like *haste, hero, house*). So I assume these were generally pronounced with an /h/, and the forms like *an household* are exceptions for some reason.

For *hundred*, *"an hundred"* appears nine times, and *"a hundred"* thirty-one. So something different seems to be going on with *"an hundred"*. You can tell from the scansion that Shakespeare pronounced *hundred* with the accent on the first syllable. So why *"an hundred"*? I don't know.

Comment: a1661   T. Fuller Worthies (1662) Somerset 31   Mounted on an horse with ten toes.

Comment: a1400   Octouian 836   What thenkest dow be an horsmonger?

Comment: More exx. in OED.

Comment: Right ... if you go far enough back in English, *an* was used for all words, even ones that started with a consonant. So I suppose *an* lasted longer for words that began with an /h/, but Shakespeare used *a horse*.

Comment: Interesting! do you have a source for this?

Comment: *Herculean* is stressed on the third syllable (of four) in BrE, with a secondary stress on the first syllable.

Comment: @Andrew: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/Herculean?q=herculean) gives second-syllable stress as a variant.

Comment: For a source that *an* is the older variant of *a*, see [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=a&allowed_in_frame=0). The change from *an* to *a* before most consonants was completed by around 1400; for words starting with an /h/, by around 1600. For words starting with an /h/ and having no stress on the first syllable, it's now complete in most dialects (but not quite all).

Comment: +1 - Wow, the things I learn from this site! I also grew up in New England (though close to NYC), and don't *remember* this as an aspect of that English. I don't know why, but in front of "Herculean", I say /eɪ/ instead of /ʌ/. I'm really interested now.

Comment: @medica: It's only a small fraction of speakers around here who do this, but I regularly hear it, and if I ever heard it before I moved here, I didn't notice it (this is quite possible).