# Why is it 'a Ukulele' and not 'an Ukulele'?

Tags: grammar

To the best of my understanding 'an' is used when a word starts with a vowel (an occasion), or sounds like it does (an honour). Ukulele sounds like it start with a ***u***, so why isn't it prefixed with an *'an'* ?

Comment: I don't think it's about a uniform or an uniform--it's about how ukulele is pronounced.  Everyone knows how to pronounce uniform, so the question is do you pronounce ukulele the same way?  Wikipedia says:  The ukulele (/juːkəˈleɪliː/ ew-kə-lay-lee, from Hawaiian: ʻukulele [ˈʔukuˈlɛlɛ] (oo-koo-leh-leh).  So it's pronounced "yoo-" in English but "oo-" in its original Hawaiian.

Comment: I downvoted because there are already many complete explanations of when to use *a* and when to use *an*, including on this site, so I don't think this question is useful.

Comment: @StevenLittman: Regardless of how *ʻukulele* is pronounced in Hawaiian, all the sources I have checked list only pronunciations starting with /j/ for the English word *ukulele.*

Comment: @sumelic, This wasn't a question about when to use a and when to use an, I've stated in my description I already understand that, it was about Ukulele in particular. Although I did figure out the answer by looking at the answer pointed to in the duplicates, it mentioned palatial approximate, reading on which led me to another answer's discussion http://english.stackexchange.com/a/155/24143 , which answered my question, but it's not as straightforward as *"already answered"*

Comment: The answers to the previous question say you use "a" before words starting with a consonant, but that is only helpful if you know whether "ukulele" starts with a consonant.  What if it starts with a non-syllabic vowel, or a semi-vowel, or a glide?  What then?

Comment: @GregLee: "The palatal approximant is a consonantal sound, even though the letter itself is a vowel. Since we use the pronunciation of the word following the article to determine whether we use 'a' or 'an', and because it is pronounced starting with a consonant, we use 'a'."

Comment: @sumelic, No, [j] is not consonantal.  Since *Preliminaries to Speech Analysis* it's been classified by most phonologists as a non-consonantal sound.  You could look it up in SPE, for instance.

Comment: @GregLee: I was quoting from the answer in the linked question. Do you have any more recent references than SPE?

Comment: @sumelic, I read the linked question and didn't think the answers given there were very good.  No, I don't have a reference at hand.

Comment: @GregLee: You say "most phonologists" rather than "all," and in a [paper](https://btk.ppke.hu/uploads/articles/6623/file/BBK-szakdolgozat-1998.pdf) I recently read by Balogné Bérces Katalin (1998) she says "Whether it [jʊ] is a single diphthong or a sequence of two phonemes is, to my best knowledge, still a matter of debate." Also, she puts "j" in a consonantal slot in words like "vineyard."  So I don't understand why you say "[j] is not consonantal" like it is an established fact. What does it mean?

Comment: @sumelic, I gave you two references, didn't I?  I see no relationship to the question about whether  [jʊ] is a single phoneme.  I don't know what "consonantal slot" means, but if the reference is to syllable structure, the appropriate feature specification would be non-syllabic (see **SPE**).

Comment: @GregLee: Ah. After more research, I see that "consonantal" is a term of art that is used in different ways from "consonant." That's pretty confusing terminology --that we can call [j] and [w] "non-consonantal consonants." I was confused because I was thinking of "consonantal" as just being the adjective form of "consonant."

Comment: @GregLee: To clarify, I misspoke when I said "consonantal slot"; I should have said "C position." That is the terminology used by Balogné Bérces.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36935/discussion-between-sumelic-and-greg-lee).