# Is the following usage of 'an' article correct?

Tags: grammar

Statement : What an illiterate group?

Is the above statement correct or do I have to use 'a' instead of 'an' since it succeeds 'what'?

Comment: It doesn't matter what is before the article. What is important is what follows the article. See also: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/when-should-i-use-a-vs-an

Comment: Please see also [ell.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of a/an depends on the sound  of the first letter of the word it *precedes*. In your case, the word after the 'a(n)' particle begins with a vowel sound, therefore **'an'** is the correct particle to use. If it were a consonant sound, 'a' would be used instead.

Examples:

1. I saw a monkey.
2. I saw an elephant.
3. I found an M&M candy in my shoe.