# To what tense this sentence belongs?

Tags: grammar

I am a little confused about the following sentence. And I have just two simple questions about it:

It is been an honour for many individuals to attend such workshop.

1) To what tense this sentence belongs?

2) when I pronounce honour I pronounce h like a ... so should I add an or a before it?

My resource: It is been a pleasure for me to work with him ...
https://youglish.com/search/It%20is%20been%20a%20pleasure?

Comment: Are you sure the sentence isn't "It **has** been..."? Also your second question is already answered [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/152/191178).

Comment: It belongs to the King James Bible tense

Comment: Hello again guys, I add my source to the question. please check it out.

Comment: @Laurel ... I add my source to the question. please check it out and help me.

Comment: @Zebrafish ... I add my source to the question. please check it out and help me.

Comment: @MohamedSheshtawy She definitely said "it **has** been..." (it's obvious to me because I'm a native AmE speaker). The captions were automatically generated, and it looks like that webpage was too. In Standard English, it is always an error to use "is been".