# Which is the correct? A universally or an universally?

Tags: sentence, subcontinental-english

Which is the correct option for below sentence?

> Who doesn't know that he is ____ universally acclaimed writter?
>
> 1) a
>
> 2) an

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does _universally_ start with a vowel or a consonant?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the word 'a' would be the most appropriate in this case.
This is quite confusing as the norm (a bit of an oxymoron when having anything to d with the English language) is to use the word 'an' when preceding a word that begins with a vowel.
However, I've seen it explained this way;
When preceding a word that starts with a vowel, the word 'an' is use except in those cases when the initial 'sound' of the word is more like a consonant.
The word 'universally' *could* be written as '**you**niversally', with the 'Y' taking on the hard sound of the letter as opposed to the 'soft' vowel sound that 'y' and 'w' often use (i.e. sunny).

Comment: This is mostly wrong. All that matters is vowels versus consonants: words like *yesterday, university, user, hierba, yerba, humor, European, yurt, hurricane* **all start with *consonants***, while words like *ylem, hour, umbilical, huevo, umbrage, ypsilon, yclept, honor* **all start with *vowels***. Then there are the very many words that **sometimes** start with vowels and **sometimes** with consonants, depending on the speaker and accent and position and utterance, including *hotelier, homage, her, him, herb, herbal, hotel, historic, opossum, Heloïs* — and perhaps even *Houston*.

Comment: If I refer to the answer that you refer to:https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/when-should-i-use-a-vs-an, then that answer is in agreement with what I said. How was that mostly wrong?  For example, I wouldn't say 'an university' or 'an user'.

Comment: When I say vowel or consonant, I'm talking about sounds. You appear to be talking about letters, which is misleading at best.