# Was 'help' pronounced starting with a vowel sound?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, history

In The King James Bible, Genesis:

> 2:20 And Adam gave names to all cattle, and to the fowl of the air, and to every beast of the field; but for Adam there was not found **an help** meet for him.

I have also found a book from 1729 by Edward Wells called *An help for the right understanding of the several divine laws and covenants, whereby man has been oblig'd thro' the several ages of the world to guide himself in order to eternal salvation*.

Does this mean that 'help' was pronounced starting with a vowel sound? Or was the rule for using the article *an* different back then?

I understand that *hour*, *honor* or *heir* have a silent 'h', coming from Latin and Greek. However, according to the American Heritage Dictionary:

> help (hĕlp)
>
> [...]
>
> [Middle English helpen, from Old English helpan.]

Maybe there were several pronunciations? How did Shakespeare pronounce it in his works?

Comment: The 'rule' doesn't apply strictly even today (this has been covered here before). It's not considered incorrect to use 'an' before (lightly, by those doing this) aspirated words such as historic(/al etc), hotel, and a few others. Though I don't.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth _The rules before "h" are a little tricky, but clear: if a word begins with an "h" sound and the first syllable is stressed (like "house"), then it never takes "an". If the first syllable is not stressed (like "historical") then it is possible to use "an"._ from [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/when-should-i-use-a-vs-an). I can't see that with 'help'. Are there English accents in which people say 'an help'?

Comment: That answer is, sadly, defective. <<The rules before "h" are a little tricky, but **clear** >> //  << If the first syllable is not stressed (like "historical") then it is possible to use "an". _Some usage authorities would say you must use "an" in those cases_ .... _You find both "a" and "an" used before words like "historical"._ >> [emphasis mine]. Please take extreme care when  quoting selectively.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I didn't quote the rest because I didn't think it was relevant, it just restricts the usage even more. What I wanted to point out with that is that _help_ is not like _historical_, it is only one syllable. It is not one of those cases.

Comment: But the statement (which you repeat as though it's uncontestable) 'The rules before "h" are a little tricky, but clear' is proved **wrong** by what follows (what follows, I believe, being certainly correct).  How can they be clear if people disagree on what they are? // Remember you responded to my "The 'rule' [whichever anyone states as being the correct prescription] doesn't apply strictly even today". I used scare quotes to show that OP's 'the rule' needs defining. (And then being seen as at best 'a guideline'.)

Comment: Some dialects still pronounce the majority of H's as silent. Spoken: *an 'ouse, an 'otel, an 'elp* etc. I could be wrong, but I believe (possibly mistakenly) that H's used to be pronounced more silently in the past. Obviously spoken and written can be quite different

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In early Middle English, people used *an* before all words, whether they started with a consonant or vowel. They started dropping the /n/ before consonants, but the /n/ was retained before /h/ longer than it was retained before other consonants.

Shakespeare seems to use "a" before almost all one-syllable words starting with "h" except ones where the "h" wasn't pronounced, like *hour, heir, herb, host*. (*A horse! a horse! my kingdom for a horse!*). However, the King James Bible, written around the same time, doesn't seem entirely consistent in their treatments of "a/an" before /h/. There are 70 instances of "an house", and 5 of "a house", in it (and 6 instances of "an horse", and none of "a horse"). Keeping the "n" was presumably thought to be the more formal way of writing things, probably because it was older.

I think it's very possible that by 1729, nobody said "an help" anymore, and that Edward Wells wrote "an help" solely because the King James Bible did.

Comment: Obviously, the AV isn't ierrant.

Comment: The inconsistency of article in the KJV is perhaps due to the many translators (I think 47) involved in it, each supplying their own idiosyncrasies.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth To err is human, as you have just demonstrated.I treat the Greek original as inspired, not the English translation (majestic though it be).

Comment: What does 'AV' mean here?

Comment: AV = "Authorized Version", the same meaning as KJV, and what it is often called in Britain.

Comment: "people used an before all words": before all words beginning with an h?

Comment: @Nigel J Obviously, translations are not guaranteed i**n**errant (I'd hoped the wordplay would be picked up); there are more serious proofs of this in the _Printers Bible_ (perhaps more comic than serious) and the _Wicked Bible_. But then the earliest manuscripts we have are not the Greek etc originals (so I'm not sure that 'treat' is warranted; I'd use 'regard').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Agreed. Only by collating the thousands of uncials', 'miniscules', 'versions', 'patristic citations' and 'lectionaries' can the science of Textual Criticism arrive at the substance of the original autographs.

Comment: @Nigel J So human effort can end up with an inerrant result if that effort is workmanlike and complex enough? I'm far from being perfectly sensitive, but I trust that the Holy Spirit will get across what He's trying to even if the version is iffy. He quotes from the Vulgate in the NT, if I remember a statement by Yancey correctly. _The Vulgate_!

Comment: @Literalman: before ***all words***. The OED has, from 1200, *Inn till an wilde wesste.* Old English didn't have an indefinite article. Middle English started using *an*, which meant *one* in Old English, for the indefinite article. The OED remarks: "Loss of the final consonant -n from the 12th cent. onwards took place chiefly, but not exclusively, before a following word with initial consonant."

Comment: (In Britain) I've never come across a silent *h* in *host*; a silent *h* in *herb* comes across as pretentious, American, or likely both. The history of which words gained the *h* sound when can't be simple

Comment: @Chris H: a silent *h* in *herb* is still standard in America (although some Americans pronounce it, possibly because of pernicious British influence). The silent *h* in *host* started being pronounced sometime after the 17th century, both in America and Britain. But some pretentious people still say *mine host*, which is a remnant of the silent "h" (*mine* used to be used before vowels and *my* before consonants).

Comment: @PeterShor interesting. I should say that my "never" wasn't actually correct - I'm originally from part of London where we're prone to dropping our *h*s; it's not unknown for me to lapse into that when exposed to such an accent. But I submitted my previous comment without saying that rather than miss my bus stop!

Comment: Richard Atkyns (1615-77) described a Royalist unit at the battle of Lansdown in 1643 as standing 'as upon the eaves of an house for steepness', so the usage lasted for several decades after the King James Bible.